# Access File from Removeable Storage in Android

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard, sd-card, android-external-storage

I am trying to access a file placed in my remove able memory card.
What I am using is

```
File f=new File("/mnt/sdcard/CAPP/");              // f.exists() returns True 
File f=new File("/mnt/sdcard/CAPP/myfile.apk");    // f.exists() returns False
```

Any idea why its happening so ? Although myfile.apk is placed in CAPP folder.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html

Comment: That path `/mnt/sdcard` is not of a removable SD card. Unless you are using a very old device.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this...

```
  String getFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "folder name" + fileName;
            File file = new File(getFile );
```

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` means we are accessing phone's external storage its not accessing remove able external storage.

Comment: Please go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location/5695129#5695129

Answer (score 0):

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourFile = new File(dir, "path/to/the/file/inside/the/myfile.apk");
```

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` means we are accessing phone's external storage its not accessing remove able external storage.

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` it means if device has any external storage it return his directory otherwise return internal storage directory.