# Get external storage path in android app for tablet

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-developer-api

How can i show  all external storage in spinner and access only external storage on selection from spinner for tablet in android app programmatically

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the path to external storage

Comment: @keser `getExternalStorageDirectory()` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

**For getting External Storage Path**  `Environment.getExternalStorageState()`

```
final String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if ( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state) ) {  // we can read the External Storage...           
    //Retrieve the External Storage:
    final File primaryExternalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    //Retrieve the External Storages from the root directory:
    final String externalStorageRootDir;
    if ( (externalStorageRootDir = primaryExternalStorage.getParent()) == null ) {  
        Log.d(TAG, "External Storage: " + primaryExternalStorage + "\n");
    }
    else {
        final File externalStorageRoot = new File( externalStorageRootDir );
        final File[] files = externalStorageRoot.listFiles();

        for ( final File file: files ) {
            if ( file.isDirectory() && file.canRead() && (file.listFiles().length > 0) ) {  // it is a directory (not a External drive)...
                Log.d(TAG, "External Storage: " + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more Info Try this link
[Find location of a removable SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-location-of-a-removable-sd-card)

Comment: `getExternalStorageDirectory()` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this lib maybe help you.
>   File and folder picker

```
 dependencies {
      compile 'com.github.isabsent:filepicker:1.1.01'
   }
```

https://github.com/isabsent/FilePicker?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=6975