# android save file/create folder to sd card

Tags: java, android, storage

I have searched on Stack Overflow already and basically answers are all using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the sd card dir.

However, in my phone it always give me `/storage/emulated/0`, which seems like the internal storage (not the real sd card), while I need a path like `/storage/6265-6530` which is the actual sd card. I have checked my sd card path is `/storage/6265-6530` in android studio.

I tried to create a folder directly using

```
File file = new File("/storage/6265-6530/MyApp/");
boolean result = file.mkdirs();
```

But the result is always `false`.

I have granted all permission like `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and request the permission in run time. But still get the error above.

While I tried to create a folder in `/storage/emulated/0` and it is ok, like below.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyApp/");
boolean result = file.mkdirs();
```

and the created path will be: "/storage/emulated/0/MyApp"

I have also tried to get sd card directory using below:

```
File[] fs = reactContext.getExternalFilesDirs(null);
fs[1].getAbsolutePath()
```

but I can only get the application-specific directories in sd card, like `/storage/6265-6530/Android/data/<my application package>/files`, not the root path of sd card.

How can I have access to write files/create folders in root path of sd card? eg. `/storage/6265-6530/`

My android version is 7.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you hardcoding the path to the SD card? Note that the SD card's folder may not be the same on all devices; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-location-of-a-removable-sd-card for more info.

Comment: I know, I just try on my own device first.

Comment: You can not write to the root of a micro sd card anymore. Only to the apps specific directory on it. Have a look at `getExternalFilesDirs()[1]`.

Comment: If you want to write on the whole removable card use the storage access framework.

Comment: @blackapps I have used saf to write a photo into root of removable card. But I can't see it in gallery. How to deal with it?

Comment: Reboot your device. Tell which Android version.

Comment: version is Android 7.0