# How to convert a list type to double array or int array?

Tags: java, arrays, list

So I want to sort a deck of cards. The constructor DeckOfCards sets up and shuffles a deck of cards. But the cards are stored in a list of type List where Card type belongs to Card class. After calling DeckOfCards I should ask the user what kind of sorting algorithm should be used to sort the deck of cards. I have just included Insertion sort at the end for example. But the insertionsort function takes in a double array. So I need to convert List list to a double array. How can I do it?

Code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

// class to represent a Card in a deck of cards
class Card 
{    
public static enum Face { Ace, Deuce, Three, Four, Five, Six,
  Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King  };
public static enum Suit { Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades };

private final Face face; // face of card
private final Suit suit; // suit of card

// two-argument constructor
public Card( Face cardFace, Suit cardSuit ) 
{   
   face = cardFace; // initialize face of card
   suit = cardSuit; // initialize suit of card
} // end two-argument Card constructor

// return face of the card
public Face getFace() 
{ 
  return face; 
} // end method getFace

// return suit of Card
public Suit getSuit() 
{ 
  return suit; 
} // end method getSuit

// return String representation of Card
public String toString()
{
   return String.format( "%s of %s", face, suit );
} // end method toString
} // end class Card

// class DeckOfCards declaration
public class DeckOfCards 
{
private List<Card> list; // declare List that will store Cards

// set up deck of Cards and shuffle
public DeckOfCards()
{
  Card[] deck = new Card[ 52 ];
  int count = 0; // number of cards

  // populate deck with Card objects
  for ( Card.Suit suit : Card.Suit.values() )  
  {
     for ( Card.Face face : Card.Face.values() )   
     {
        deck[ count ] = new Card( face, suit );
        count++;
     } // end for
  } // end for

  list = Arrays.asList( deck ); // get List
  Collections.shuffle( list );  // shuffle deck
} // end DeckOfCards constructor

// output deck
public void printCards()
{
  // display 52 cards in two columns
  for ( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ )
     System.out.printf( "%-20s%s", list.get( i ),
        ( ( i + 1 ) % 2 == 0 ) ? "\n" : "" );
} // end method printCards

public static void main( String args[] )
{
  DeckOfCards cards = new DeckOfCards();
  cards.printCards();
  //add code here to take input from user and sort
  int a;
  System.out.println("\nSort the deck of cards");
  System.out.println("\nEnter your choice: \n1.Selection Sort \n2.Insertion Sort 
\n3.Merge       Sort\n");
  //take input
  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
  a=reader.nextInt();
  switch(a)
  {
    case 1:
        //call Selection sort
        break;
    case 2:
        //call Insertion sort
        break;
    case 3:
        //call Merge sort
        break;
  }
 } // end main  

//Insertion sort

} // end class DeckOfCards
public class InsertionSort {
/** The method for sorting the numbers */
public static void insertionSort(double[] list) {
for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
  /** insert list[i] into a sorted sublist list[0..i-1] so that
       list[0..i] is sorted. */
  double currentElement = list[i];
  int k;
  for (k = i - 1; k >= 0 && list[k] > currentElement; k--) {
    list[k + 1] = list[k];
  }

  // Insert the current element into list[k+1]
  list[k + 1] = currentElement;
}
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert list to array in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572795/convert-list-to-array-in-java)

Comment: From what magical place that `double[]` array sorting comes from in that code?

Comment: Write a sort method that takes a `List<? extends Comparable>` and have your Card implement Comparable.

Comment: @Andrew Its not a dupplicate, there Arrays of Objects are the result, he wants array of primitive type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to convert a list of `Card` objects, i.e. `List<Card> list` you could easily change it to a `Card` array (i.e. `Card[]`) using a method provided by `List` itself called [`toArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)

However, you have some confusion in what you're asking. You are expecting that a method that expects an array of `double` suddenly magically knows how to treat objects of type `Card`. How can a `Card` suddenly behave like a double precision number?

You should change the method `insertionSort()` first (which you probably copied from somewhere without trying to understand what its doing) to take a `Card[]` array first, and then modify what its doing internally so that the comparison happens on the properties of the `Card` object rather than the `double` primitive.

On the other hand, you might be interested to know that Java already provides sorting functions through the `Arrays` class. You can have a look at the function [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29). However you still need to implement the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface so that Java knows how to sort the array, it doesn't know how your `Card` objects should be sorted (by face? by suit? in which order? Java doesn't know how to play cards), so you need to make your `Card` objects implement `Comparable` and have a [`compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) method which helps Java decide which `Card` instance comes before which.  You can use the same approach if you still want to implement the sorting yourself and change the method `insertionSort()` to take an array of `Comparable` items and inside it you call `compareTo()` to know which item comes before what.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you want to sort your Cards with different algorithms. And your implementation of algorithms accept only `double` array.

Two question you need to think about:

- The rule of Card comparison, e.g. Heart Ace > Diamonds Ace?
- if all sortings are **comparison sort** algorithm?

If the answer of the 2nd question is:  **YES**

I suggest you stopping thinking about converting Card Array type to double array. Instead, making your all algorithm implementation more generic, for example, accept `Comparable[] arr` array, or even `Card[] arr`. Then make your `Card` class implement Comparable interface. Implement your card comparison rule in `compareTo(Card c)` method.

Comment: So you mean within the algorithm function body I should pass a Card[] arr instead of a double[] arr?

Comment: `Comparable[]` would be better, because it could be used for any case.  of course, only if all your sorting are **comparison sort**

Comment: Thanks everyone. I figured it out. Everyone here has helped me in someway to get me through. THanks again!