# Convert Arraylist<<Post>> to Array

Tags: java, android

I want to retrive values from the `getNombre()` and put it in a new array not arraylist. The job is done from a background task.

```
public class Post {

private String nombre;

public void setNombre(String nombre) {

    this.nombre = nombre;

}

public String getNombre() {

    return nombre;

}
}
```

I call my postlist as follows:

```
ArrayList<Post> PostList = new ArrayList<Post>();
```

In my background task I have the following post excuse method.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Post> result) {

}
```

How can I put `getNombre()` values into a new array, not `ArrayList`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9572820/597657

Comment: What you exactly want to do? getNombre() returns string not array nor arraylist. If you want to make array with single string, do this `return new String[] { nombre }`

Comment: i want to get each value from getNombre() and stored it in a simple array of string

Comment: `getNombre().split("-");` will return array of `String`

Comment: result.get(position).getThumbnail().split(""); but how can put values resulted from this array in a new array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code for putting value returned by getNombre() of all Post in ArrayList into String[].

```
protected String[] getAllNombres( ArrayList<Post> posts ) {
    String[] nombres = new String[ posts.size ];
    int i = 0;
    for( Post post : posts ) {
        nombres[i++] = post.getNombre();
    }
    return nombres;
}
```