# how to read float array from command line in java?

Tags: java

How can I store float value in an array from command line and when user input character "q" then system stop inputting values from command line.

Comment: You need to write a little program using `Scanner.java`. Read one token at a time, exit when it's q otherwise parse into float and store in a float array.

Comment: In addition to @YogendraSingh, I would paste those values into List, which you will then can [convert to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572795/convert-list-to-array-in-java)

Comment: Seems like your life depends on this code.

Comment: In order to answer this question, we'll need more specific information. How should the array be entered, and what is the dimension of the array (i. e., is it a 2-dimensional array or a 1-dimensional array)?

Comment: Dear Green! its only 1-dimensional float array but size of the array is not know in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but wrote using [Scanner docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while(sc.hasNext()) {
  String next = sc.next();
  if("q".equals(next)) break;

  float value = new Float(next);
  System.out.println("Float: "+value);
}
```

Comment: Your comment prompted me to test it. It seems to work ok.

Comment: Dear! I need an float array and its size is not known in advance