# How to convert List<String> to String array

Tags: java

I was trying to convert `List<String>` to `String[] allAim= new String[25];` i.e. into `allAim` string array,
code snippet is:

```
List<String> myString = new ArrayList<String>();
myString=db.getAllAlarmAim();
Object[] mStringArray = myString.toArray();
for(int i = 0; i < mStringArray.length ; i++) {
    Log.d("string is",(String)mStringArray[i]);
    allAim[i]=(String)mStringArray[i].toString(); 
}
```

but when I try to access `allAim`, the app crashes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert list to array in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572795/convert-list-to-array-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code, you can convert `List<String>` `myString` to `String[] mStringArray` as follows:

```
 Object[] mStringArray = myString.toArray(new String[myString.size()]);
```

your code will be:

```
    List<String> myString = new ArrayList<String>();
    myString=db.getAllAlarmAim();
   Object[] mStringArray= myString.toArray(new String[myString.size()]);

    for(int i = 0; i < mStringArray.length ; i++){
        Log.d("string is", (String)mStringArray[i]);
    }
```

Comment: you don't need both. either `myString.toArray(mStringArray);` or `mStringArray= myString.toArray(new String[0]);` is sufficient

Comment: I know, just to be according with their code, i have updated my answer, thank you.

Comment: First two lines can be collapsed into `List<String> myString = db.getAllAlarmAim();`

Comment: 'for(int i = 0; i < mStringArray.length ; i++){
            Log.d("string is", (String)mStringArray[i]);
        allAlarmAim[i]= (String)mStringArray[i];
        }
        
        aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,allAlarmAim);
        l1.setAdapter(aa);'  HERE allAlarmAim does not get any values,WHY???

Comment: in the code snippet i have mentioned about array allAim,  WHY CANT I USE THIS ARRAY OUTSIDE LOOP TO populate list