# Error trying to convert list to an array[]

Tags: java, arrays, list, int, type-conversion

I have referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572795/convert-list-to-array-in-java) in an attempt to convert my list to an array, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is what I have:

```
    int values[] = Arrays.asList(str.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", " ").trim().split(" ")).toArray();
```

The error that I am getting (type mismatch) is stating that I should change the type of values[] from `int` to `object`

The end result should just be an array of numbers. 
Example: a-9000xyz89 would be an array with [-9000, 89] as the values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) will return `String[]` and not `int[]`. You have to iterate over `String[]` and create `int[]`. Moreover, you don't need to convert array to list with `Arrays.asList`.

For example,

```
String str = "1 2 3 4";
String arr[] = str.split(" ");
int[] ans = new int[arr.length];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    ans[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ans));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

EDIT

> I am getting the same error when I remove the `toArray()` and when I
>   change `values[] to a String[]. String values[] =
>   Arrays.asList(question.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", " ").trim().split("
>   "));`

Note that `Arrays.asList` in your case will return `List<String>` but type of `values` is `String[]`.

You can directly store result of `split` in values,

```
String values[] = question.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", " ").trim().split(" ");
```

Comment: I am getting the same error when I remove the toArray() and when I change values[] to a String[].     String values[] = Arrays.asList(question.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", " ").trim().split(" "));

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that, for my case will not work because I do not want to separate every number from each other; I only want to separate the numbers from the string. So if I had a string = "xyq123x1" it should return [123, 1] instead of [1, 2, 3, 1].

Answer (score 0):

Following will work for Java 8

```
int[] values = Arrays.stream(str.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", " ").trim().split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Note - `[^-?0-9]+` does not support strings such as *a-90-00xyz89* or *a-9000x-yz89* because it will produce non-integers