# Extract strings using Jsoup

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get some name form `class` attribute within a website `html` page by using `Jsoup` Library, The problem is that i'm getting the elements by class using  `getElementsByClass("name")` and store it into a string variable and
the result coming like this "mike andro rob banks maria gerardo louis....etc".
but what i want is to separate the individual names and store them into array.
the following is the code snippet:

```
public String processText(String htmlPage) {

    Document html = Jsoup.parse(htmlPage);
    String names = html.body().getElementsByClass("name").text();
    return names;
}
```

**More information:**

The source page is an `html` page and i am saving the full html code in a string and then process the string to extract only the Elements under the `class="name"`

`htmlPage` which i am passing to `processText` method is similar to the following:

```html
<div class="name">
       Rob Kardashian
      </div>
     </div>
    </a>
   </div>
     <div class="channelListEntry">
    <a href="/zayn_malik">
     <div class="image">
      <img src="http://cdn.posh24.com/images/:profile/014cf47ca44daf8f44a3e0720929ee327" alt="Zayn Malik"/>
     </div>
     
      
          <div class="info">
      <div class="status-container">
       <div class="position">4</div>
        
        <div class="img pos"></div>
        <div class="value">+12</div>
             
      </div>
      <div class="name">
       Zayn Malik
      </div>
     </div>
    </a>
   </div>
     <div class="channelListEntry">
    <a href="/kanye_west">
     <div class="image">
      <img src="http://cdn.posh24.com/images/:profile/03f352f71ffab135cd81821eb190d4832" alt="Kanye West"/>
     </div>
     
      
          <div class="info">
      <div class="status-container">
       <div class="position">5</div>
        
        <div class="img pos"></div>
        <div class="value">+16</div>
             
      </div>
      <div class="name">
       Kanye West
      </div>
     </div>
    </a>
   </div>
     <div class="channelListEntry">
    <a href="/kendall_jenner">
     <div class="image">
      <img src="http://cdn.posh24.com/images/:profile/066d5c02547c4357f1bc5f633c68f4085" alt="Kendall Jenner"/>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use `split` function to get an array from string

```
String arr[]=names.trim().split("\\s");
```

plus if you have spaces and tab combined between name then use

```
  String arr[]=names.split("\\s+");
```

Update:

```
      ArrayList<String>  name=new ArrayList<String>();
      for (Element output: html.body().getElementsByClass("name")) {
          name.add(output.text());
          }
```

[example link](http://www.posh24.com/celebrities)

Output :

[image]

[link to convert list to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572795/convert-list-to-array-in-java)

Comment: please note that the string contain each person name and lastname

Comment: let just say some people have last name and some don't or some have first+middle+last name then how you will make the difference between "jhon snow robert" as single name

Comment: that is why im asking im trying to save the name in the array right from the source from HTML code using the Jsoup library

Comment: in the source page it looks like this <div class="name">
       Jamie Foxx
      </div>

Comment: put these new updates into your post to make it clear what you exactly want