# ArrayList to user defined class array

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a `List<User> userList` need to convert to `UserData[]`

```
for(int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++){
    userData[i] = userList.get(i);
}
```

It always returns `null` though the list size is 1. can anyone help on this.

Comment: Place the complete code

Comment: Maybe your list contains `null`? Also, show us the declarations and initializations of `userData[]` and `userList`, please.

Comment: show the `return` statement

Comment: Have initialize the variable new UserData[userList.size()]?

Comment: “It always returns `null`” What, exactly, returns null?  Nothing in the code you’ve shown can “return” anything.

Comment: Are there really two different classes? User and user data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert list to array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572795/convert-list-to-array-in-java)

Comment: @VGR i have the object with all the data set to it. it throws invocation targetexception I think its because of the array intialization

Comment: @Ghostcat no they are same

Comment: Edit your question and show the *entire* stack trace of your exception, including all “Caused by” sections.  Also show us the line of code which causes the exception;  it will be stated in the first line in the final “Caused by” section of the stack trace.

Comment: You want to read [mcve] and improve your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collections can be converted to arrays:

```
UserData[] userArray = userList.toArray(new UserData[userList.size()])
```

Comment: won't work. [`toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray--) returns `Object[]`

Comment: Correct, sorry about that

Comment: Would work, but `new UserData[0]` is faster. Apart from that, it's `userList.size()`

Comment: @ChandlerBing i tried with your solution i get ArrayIndexOutof BoundException error

Comment: this solved the issue i directly added to the setters so i accept this answer

Answer (score 3):

just another option, this time using the power of java8 streams:

```
List<Foo> myList = Arrays.asList(new Foo(), new Foo(), new Foo(), new Foo());
Foo[] stringArray = myList.stream().toArray(Foo[]::new);
```

Edit:

Stream is actually not necessary so you can still do:

```
Foo[] fooArray = myList.toArray(new Foo[0])
```

Comment: not really necessary to use a stream here. Foo[] fooArray = myList.toArray(new Foo[0]);

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code try this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListTest {

static UserData[] userdata = new UserData[3];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayListTest alt = new ArrayListTest();
    ArrayList<UserData> users = alt.arrayTest();

    for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
        userdata[i] = users.get(i);
    }

    for (UserData ud : userdata) {
        System.out.println("User Name " + ud.getName());

    }

}

private ArrayList<UserData> arrayTest() {
    ArrayList<UserData> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    userList.add(new UserData("user 1"));
    userList.add(new UserData("user 2"));
    userList.add(new UserData("user 3"));
    return userList;
}

private class UserData {

    private final String name;

    public UserData(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}

}
```

[this is the output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmcWg.png)