# Populating JComboBox with TypedQuery<Entity> does not show Entitys name correct

Tags: java, arrays, database, jpa, objectdb

I want get the name of each object in this return list, but the output is an array of Object[], and this show entitys.Categoria[id=1] in my JComboBox control.

I not understand this. Please help me! This is my code:

```
public List<Categoria> consultarCategorias() {
    try {            
        TypedQuery<Categoria> q = 
                em.createQuery("select c from Categoria c", Categoria.class);
            List<Categoria> results = q.getResultList();            
            return results;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note: I use this

```
for (Categoria c : results) {
   System.out.println(c.getName());
}
```

and not work, this show the result cannot convert to Categoria

This is the code to fill my JComboBox:

```
public void fillCmbCategorias() {
   cmbCategoria.removeAllItems();
   try {
      Object[] listaCategorias = crud.consultarCategorias().toArray();
      DefaultComboBoxModel dcb = new DefaultComboBoxModel(listaCategorias);
      cmbCategoria.setModel(dcb);
   } catch (Exception e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null
              ,"No se pudo cargar la lista de categorias. " + e.getMessage());
   }
}
```

Comment: So is `results` obtained like `List<Categoria> results = consultarCategorias()`? What is the actual error and where do you see it? Can you paste the part of code from the context you declare List<Categoria>?

Comment: Or is the error actually when you run `consultarCategorias()` and there `q.getResultList();`?

Comment: Yes, the results obtained as objects: I invoke that method from JFrame: this is the code to fill my JComboBox :

Comment: Object[] listaCategorias = crud.consultarCategorias().toArray();
            DefaultComboBoxModel dcb = new DefaultComboBoxModel(listaCategorias);
            cmbCategoria.setModel(dcb);

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Oh, I already understand, work correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only reason i can imagine that you have declared the `result` as some super type list, like `List<?>` or `List<Object>`.

Assuming you can assing the return value of `consultarCategorias()` to it.

And of course you should not do it this way - you should correct the list generic type - but this might then work:

```
for (Object c : results) {
   System.out.println(((Categoria)c).getName());
}
```

Update (after problem code added):

Your problem seems be this:

```
Object[] listaCategorias = crud.consultarCategorias().toArray();
```

as i suspected.

Try

```
Categoria[] listaCategorias =
   crud.consultarCategorias().toArray(new Categoria[]{});
// toArray() needs some array instance to determine the type
```

About `List`s and converting to `Array`s see more here [Convert list to array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572795/convert-list-to-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try casting like this :

```
List<Categoria> results = (List<Categoria>)q.getResultList();  `
```