# Convert ArrayList data to specified String[] with comma seperated?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert ArrayList<String> to String []](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374311/convert-arrayliststring-to-string)

How do I convert an `ArrayList` to a `String[]`?

For example, my `ArrayList` is

```
arrlist=[audio,video,song,tech]
```

I want to convert it to a `String[]` like this:

```
String[] data;

data={ "audio","video","song","tech"};
```

My issue is that `ArrayList` data can be changed dynamically, but I would like a return format in a finite sized array.

Comment: ever tried java.util.ArrayList.toArray() method ?

Comment: please google it it is vaey simple BTW 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374311/convert-arrayliststring-to-string

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29):

```
ArrayList<?> foo;
String[] data = foo.toArray(new String[foo.size()]);
```

You don't have to pass a non-zero length array to this function, but if you do and it's big enough, toArray will simply use it, if you don't then toArray will make a second allocation. This isn't so much a fine optimization point; rather, it's the standard convention.

Also note that the `String[]` is not immutable, it's only fixed size. Both the `ArrayList` and `String[]` will allow your data to "change"; if you want an immutable list (a list that cannot be edited and which contents cannot be replaced), you can find one in Google Guava, or implement your own trivially.

Answer (score 2):

from

[Convert ArrayList<String> to String[] array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374311/convert-arrayliststring-to-string)

```
 ArrayList<String> stock_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    stock_list.add("stock1");
    stock_list.add("stock2");
    String[] stockArr = new String[stock_list.size()];
    stockArr = stock_list.toArray(stockArr);
    for(String s : stockArr)
        System.out.println(s);
```

from http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/06/convert-arraylist-to-arrays-in-java.html

Comment: Copy & past-ing other answers isn't very nice...

Comment: I am giving reference that's why I mentioned the original link as well.

Comment: I don't think any thing wrong if the two question are same then there is any thing wrong to giving reference of the other... I am not copying answer in same post...

Comment: such things are to be done as comments,not answers. References + new view points,new things about the answers can be posted as answers. But just a copy paste shouldn't be done.

Comment: @Kazekage Gaara agreed ... 'll keep in mind for future .........