# ArrayList to Array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, arraylist

How do I convert this ArrayList's value into an array? So it can look like,

```
String[] textfile = ... ;
```

The values are Strings (words in the text file), and there are more than a 1000 words. In this case I cannot do the, words.add("") 1000 times. How can I then put this list into an array?

```
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String stringSearch = scan.nextLine();

        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(); //convert to array
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("File1.txt"));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {                
            words.add(line);
        }
```

Comment: why can't you do `words.add(...)` 1000 times?

Comment: It is hard to understand the essence of your question. What is the problem with calling words.add() 1000 times?

Comment: I would start by asking why you want an array of Strings? Unless you have an API that only takes arrays, you can use `List` in place of an array. Especially given that `ArrayList` is backed by an array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert ArrayList<String> to String \[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374311/convert-arrayliststring-to-string)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use

```
String[] textfile = words.toArray(new String[words.size()]);
```

---

**Relevant Documentation**

- [`List#toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 0):

`words.toArray()` should work fine.

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] wordsArray = (String[]) words.toArray();
```

Comment: I think this will cause a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the toArray method of Collection such as shown here

[Collection toArray example](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/util/CollectionToArrayExample.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
words.add("w1");
words.add("w2");
String[] textfile = new String[words.size()];
textfile = words.toArray(textfile);
```