# Selenium WebDriver wait until combined ExpectedConditions (AND, OR, NOT operators)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to make Selenium WebDriver wait until combined expected condition?

Basically the similar question for Java has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14840884/7732200) and [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37898503/7732200), but such method `OR` ([docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#or-org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition...-)) isn't here for Python binding ([expected_conditions.py](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py) on GitHub)

I have a very slow callback that results in one of the following:

- a div with id=`_report_success` if everything has been loaded correctly
- a div with id=`_report_error` in case of any failure

So, I need to wait until either `_report_success` or `_report_error` becomes visible.

Separately these conditions are pretty straightforward:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, '_report_success')))

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, '_report_error')))
```

In Java the combined version looks like the following:

```
driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.or(
        ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(...),
        ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(...)
));
```

Of course, I can make a loop and check the presence of both with an interval (actually like it's implemented in WebDriverWait.until), but I'm looking for more elegant and flexible solution. After all, if the method for such needs is present in Java version, why it's not in a Python binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `css_selector` for `OR`

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#_report_success, #_report_error')))
```

Comment: Thank you, definitely good solution for this particular case. But in general, we may need to combine different expected conditions. If there will be no answers with a general approach, I accept this one.