# Array List<File> to Array File[]

Tags: java, arrays, file, arraylist

I have to form an ArrayList to an "normal" Array File[].

```
File[] fSorted = (File[]) x.toArray();
```

The Error: `Cast Exception`

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.io.File;
```

How can I return the list `x` as File[ ]-List?

--

My function:

```
private File[] sortFiles(File[] files){;

    ArrayList<String> allFiles = new ArrayList<String>() ;
    for (int index = 0; index < files.length; index++)  
    {  
        File afile = new File(files[index].toString());
        allFiles.add(afile.getPath().toString());

    } 
    java.util.Collections.sort(allFiles);

    ArrayList<File> x = new ArrayList<File>();
    for(int i = 0; i< allFiles.size(); ++i){
        x.add(new File(allFiles.get(i)));
    }
    File[] fSorted = (File[]) x.toArray();

    return fSorted;

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert ArrayList<String> to String \[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374311/convert-arrayliststring-to-string)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert list to array in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572795/convert-list-to-array-in-java)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use:

```
File[] fSorted = x.toArray(new File[x.size()]);
```

Comment: +1 My self, I prefer `Foo[] array = new Foo[list.size()]; list.toArray(array);` just for readability :)