# ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[] android

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

In my application I need to convert my arraylist to a string of an array. However, I am getting an error:

```
ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[] android
```

At the line with `listofurls` I am getting the error: `listofurls = (String[])image_urls.toArray();`

This is the full code:

```
public class Test2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{
  String[] listofurls ;
  private static final String url = "http://www.tts.com/album_pro/array_to_encode";
  JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
  ArrayList<String> image_urls = new ArrayList<String>();

  protected void onPreExecute() {
    //Log.e(LOG_CLASS, "in side assyntask");
  }

  protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    Log.v("Async","Async");
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
      JSONObject seo = json.getJSONObject("SEO");
      JSONArray folio = seo.getJSONArray("Folio");

      // JSONArray image_urls1 = new JSONArray();
      //String s1=seo.getString("Folio");

      for(int i=0;i<folio.length();++i) {
        String m = folio.getString(i);
        Log.v("M"+i,m);
        image_urls.add(m);
        Log("test-url"+image_urls);
      }
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    listofurls = (String[])image_urls.toArray();  //ERROR OCCURS HERE

    return null;
  }

  private void Log(String string) {
    Log.v("Test",string);
  }

  protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) { }

  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    mAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),listofurls.length );
    mAdapter.setImageurls(listofurls);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
  }
```

Comment: @MiserableVariable Better wording, yes ..

Comment: actually opposite meaning, but you get the point :)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

try

```
listofurls = image_urls.toArray(new String[image_urls.size()]);
```

Note: I suggest to rename listofurls to arrayOfURLs

Comment: still getting the error.it says, Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]

Comment: you mean to say : String[] listofurls ; listofurls = image_urls.toArray(new String[image_urls.size()]);   , instead of "listofurls" i should use "arrayOFURLs"?? but how does it make a difference

Comment: i suggest to try and localize the problem, try this: List<String> image_urls = new ArrayList<String>(); String[] listofurls = image_urls.toArray(new String[image_urls.size()]);

Comment: @Shweta Naming conventions. If you're calling your array a list, it's confusing.

Answer (score 30):

You should use `toArray` as mentioned above, but not in that way.

Either initialize the array first and fill it:

```
String[] urlArray = new String[image_urls.size()];
image_urls.toArray(urlArray);
```

After which, `urlArray` will contain all the Strings from `image_urls`, or pass in a zero-length String array:

```
listofurls = (String[]) image_urls.toArray(new String[0]);
```

See the documentation for [`toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.lang.Object[])).

Comment: Other solutions didn't work for me. Passing 0 length array worked.

Comment: This is right solution, Just no need for casting to `(String[])`

Answer (score 3):

You just need to get the contents of arraylist in an array, right??

Can't u do like this?

```
       for(int i=0;i<folio.length();++i)
        {
            String m = folio.getString(i);
            Log.v("M"+i,m);
            image_urls.add(m);
            Log("test-url"+image_urls);


            listofurls[i] = m ;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
listofurls = image_urls.toArray(new String[0]);
```

that should do the trick for all cases, even if you don't know the size of the resulting array.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<String> stock_list = new ArrayList<String>();
stock_list.add("stock1");
stock_list.add("stock2");
String[] stockArr = new String[stock_list.size()];
stockArr = stock_list.toArray(stockArr);
for(String s : stockArr)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Taken directly from here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374311/convert-arrayliststring-to-string)