# why can't cast Object[] to String[]

Tags: java, arrays, casting

1. No error

   ```
   Object[] a = new String[]{"12","34","56"};
   String[] b = (String[]) a;
   ```
2. No error

   ```
   Object a = new String[]{"12","34","56"};    
   String[] b = (String[]) a;
   ```
3. Run time error : ClassCastException

   ```
   Object[] a = new Object[3];
   a[0] = "12";
   a[1] = "34";
   a[2] = "56";
   String[] b = (String[]) a;
   ```
4. Run time error : ClassCastException

   ```
   Object[] a = {"12","34","56"};    
   String[] b = (String[]) a;
   ```

Of course, we can downcast  an `Object[]` variable back to `String[]` if it was created as an `String[]`.

My question is why we can not cast `Object[]` to `String[]` when it was created as `Object[]` but all its members are String? Is it because of security reason or just not that useful to implement this?

Comment: Assylias provided a good answer from JLS' perspective.Alex explained why JLS does not allow this.So Alex's answer is what I'm after. Thanks all, guys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's two reasons I can think of.

Firstly, if you change the *original* array, the casted array can become invalid. e.g.

```
 Object[] a = {"12","34","56"};   
 String[] b = (String[]) a; // pretend this is legal. a and b now point to the same array

 a[0] = new Object(); // clearly ok
 String x = b[0]; // No longer a string! Bad things will happen!
```

Secondly, the example you have chosen is very simple, but if you have a very large `Object[]` array and it's not clear to the compiler what is filling it, then it has no way of validating that every element of the array satisfies the cast.

```
Object[] a = new Object[10000];
// lots of weird and whacky code to fill the array with strings

String[] b= (String[]) a; // valid or no? The best-defined answer is to say no.
```

Answer (score 5):

It is defined in the [JLS #5.5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.3). In substance, a cast:

```
 r = new RC[]; TC[] t = (TC[]) r;
```

"works" at runtime iif RC is a subtype of TC (or TC itself). Whether RC actually only contains TCs is irrelevant and the compile-time type of r is not used either (what matters is the runtime type):

- you can write: `r = new String[]; Object[] t = (Object[]) r;`, but
- you can't write `r = new Object[]; String[] t = (String[]) r;`.

JLS extract:

> If T is an array type TC[], that is, an array of components of type TC, then a run-time exception is thrown unless one of the following is true:
>
> - TC and RC are the same primitive type.
> - TC and RC are reference types and type RC can be cast to TC by a recursive application of these run-time rules for casting.

In your examples 3 and 4, RC = Object and TC = String and Object is not a subtype of String.
In your examples 1 and 2, RC = String and TC = String so it works.

Note: the type in this context is the runtime type.

Comment: In JLS, it's TC[] = (TC[]) RC[]. So RC is Object and TC is Sting.And Object can be cast to String if it is Sting.So still I don't understand.

Comment: The JLS does not explain why case 1 and 2 are allowed, which cast object[] to String[]

Comment: And I have elaborated a little more. In your first example, you are not casting an `Object[]` to a `String[]`, you are casting a `String[]` (runtime type) to a `String[]`, which is allowed.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are **not casting individual member** of array, you are **casting the whole array instance** which is of type `Object[]` and not `String[]`.

```
Object[] a = new String[]{"12","34","56"};
```

Here the instance is of type `String[]` and the compile time type is `Object[]`.

And in the next line you are casting it back to `String[]` which is allowed as the actual type or runtime type is `String[]`.

But `Object[] a = new Object[3];` here the actual type and Compile time type is `Object[]` and it is not `String[]`. So an `Object[]` cannot be `String[]`.

```
Object[] a = new Object[1];
a[0] = "a"; //Actual type String
```

So you can do this:

```
String aStr = (String)a[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Array objects are not just a collection of their elements, they have classes just like other objects. The class for array of strings is a subclass of array of objects. That's why there's no error in your 1 or 2, but the last two are equivalent to

```
Object o = new Object();
String s = (String) o;
```

Comment: This is interesting.Can you show me what the name of class array and the class name of String[]??

Comment: @DonLi: They don't have a friendly name (other than `Object[]` or `String[]`).  The internal name is something like `[Ljava.lang.Object;` or `[Ljava.lang.String;`.

Comment: The class name of string array is `[Ljava.lang.String;`. Since it's not a valid identifier you can't use it directly in a program, but you can use it with the reflection API for example.

Comment: you can define an array and do a `getClass()` on that array instance and print that and you will get that representation.

Comment: Even simpler: the the class object literal `String[].class`

Answer (score 2):

If all members Object array were Strings at the moment of casting you still could assign objects that are not Strings to the elements of this array later. So you would have String array with elements which are not Strings.

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264182/classcastexception-java-lang-object-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-string-andr) provides a way to quickly create a `String[]` out of an `Object[]`.

```
arrayOfUrls = imageUrls.toArray(new String[imageUrls.size()]);
```

Assuming of course that `imageUrls` is not `null`.