# Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljavax.servlet.http.Cookie;

Tags: java, arrays, collections, classcastexception

I have written a custom RequestWrapper to add cookies in to the request

```
    @Override
 public Cookie[] getCookies()
 {
         Cookie c=new Cookie("iPlanetDirectoryPro", "macleanpinto");
    Cookie c1=new Cookie("iPlanetDirectoryPro1", "macleanpinto1");

      Collection<Cookie> result = new ArrayList<Cookie>(2);

         result.add(c); 
         result.add(c1);
        return (Cookie[]) result.toArray();


 }
```

The above code at Return throws java.lang.ClassCastException. I am not able to be figure out why it does. Since i have created collection of cookies and i am trying return array list of cookies.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try `result.toArray(new Cookie[2]);` instead of `(Cookie[]) result.toArray();`?

Reason being - calling just  `result.toArray();` returns `Object[]`

If you see the source code of ArrayList

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
}
```

and

```
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
    if (a.length < size)
        // Make a new array of a's runtime type, but my contents:
        return (T[]) Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, a.getClass());
System.arraycopy(elementData, 0, a, 0, size);
    if (a.length > size)
        a[size] = null;
    return a;
}
```

here the latter, clearly uses `Arrays.copyOf` passing the type of array

And `Object[]` can't be cast to `Cookie[]`

Answer (score 2):

Try using `ArrayList.toArray(T[] a)`.

Example:

```
return result.toArray(new Cookie[result.size()]);
```

As stated in the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), `ArrayList.toArray()` returns an array of type Object. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119494/why-cant-cast-object-to-string) a thread explaining why you can't cast Object[] to String[]. Even though you're using Cookie[] the same principle applies.

Comment: IMO, the simplest and most straightforward answer. And it works!

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` internally uses an `Object[]` to store the elements. So, when you use `ArrayList#toArray()` method, it returns the `Object[]`.

Now, you cannot cast from an `Object[]` to a `Cookie[]`, b'coz `Object` is not a subtype, but a supertype of `Cookie`. For example, consider below code:

```
Object[] objArray = {"a", 1, new Date()};    // an Object[]
Cookie[] cookieArray = (Cookie[]) objArray;  // You don't expect this to run
```

So, if you want an `Cookie[]`, you have to iterate over the `Object[]` and manually convert each element to `Cookie` type, and add it to a new array. That is what `ArrayList#toArray(T[])` does.

So, you can change your return statement to:

```
return result.toArray(new Cookie[result.size()]);
```

I've taken `result.size()` to avoid creation of an extra array in the method. You could have passed `new Cookie[0]` too. But, a new array will be created inside the `toArray` method.