# AsyncTask: ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

In my application I run these code for gcm ccs(xmpp) and the code shows following error An error occurred while executing `doinbackground.excute()`
This is the code:

```
sendTask = new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
    protected String doInBackground(String... title) {

        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("ACTION", action);
        data.putString("CLIENT_MESSAGE", "Hello GCM CCS XMPP!");
        String id = Integer.toString(ccsMsgId.incrementAndGet());

        try {
            Log.d("RegisterActivity", "messageid: " + id);
            gcm.send(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com", id,
                     data);
            Log.d("RegisterActivity", "After gcm.send successful.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Exception: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Sent message.";
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        sendTask = null;
        // tosat about the success in return
    }
};

sendTask.execute(null, null, null);
```

Comment: Why arent you calling simply sendTask.execute();

Comment: while the exception is the same as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264182/classcastexception-java-lang-object-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-string-andr, the context and the reason why it is generated is different.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How is your `sendTask` declared? I suppose its simply `AsyncTask sendTask;`, if so then change it to:

```
AsyncTask<String, String, String> sendTask;
```

---

The cause of this exception is similar to the one that occurs in below code:

```
Object arr1[] = new Object[] {null,null,null};
String arr2[] = (String[])arr1; // here java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
```

VarArgs in java are implemented as arrays, so when you declare sendTask as `AsyncTask<String, String, String>` then compiler will call your `doInBackground` with `new String[]{null,null,null}`, but when you declare it as `AsyncTask` then `doInBackground` is called with `new Object[]{null,null,null}`.

Because of type erasure, compiler will add hidden implicit cast from `Object[]` to `String[]`. This is to allow code as below to work correctly:

```
  AsyncTask sendTask = ...;
  Object[] arg = new String[]{null,null,null};
  sendTask.execute(arg);
```

Comment: but i am facing one more problem can u please help me out

Comment: @AlkaNigam If its not related to above problem - then its better if you create a new question

Answer (score 0):

Try

`sendTask.execute(new String[]{""});`

instead of

```
sendTask.execute(null, null, null);
```