# How to convert a collection to an Array

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I need a function that returns dates as an Array.

The `getItem()` below must return dates as an Array.

```
public class Calendar implements Ownable {
    User owner;
    ArrayList<CalendarItem> Termin = new ArrayList<CalendarItem>();

    public Calendar (User owner){
        this.owner = owner; 
    }

    @Override
    public Person getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
    public CalendarItem [] getItems(){
        return ; //  what should I return here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Termin.toArray(new CalendarItem[0]);

Comment: Actually your question is how to convert ArrayList to plain Array, isn't it?

Comment: It's absolutely wrong to name variables in Java with capital letter. Stick to conventions!

Comment: i can find a possible duplicate, but just feeling lazy ^^

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert list to array in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572795/convert-list-to-array-in-java)

Comment: @anvarik - there you are :-)

Answer (score 3):

Note - Termin is badly named, variables should all be in camel case.

```
public CalendarItem [] getItems(){
    return Termin.toArray(new CalendarItem[Termin.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Convert ArrayList to String []](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374311/convert-arrayliststring-to-string)  and [toArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28%29).

Try this:

```
public CalendarItem [] getItems(){
    return Termin.toArray(new CalendarItem[Termin.size()]);
}
```