# Array of objects in a class

Tags: java

I am trying to create an array of a class within a class so that I can have multiple sets of the inner class. However because I cannot create an empty an array in Java, I was wonder what's the best way to set this up. I know I can just define an array that is bigger than I would ever use but I feel that kind of sloppy programming.

Here's the important part of the 2 classes:

```
public class xmldata {
    String Barcode;
    String First;
    String Last;
    String Phone;
    String Email;

    String md5sum;

    String zipfile;

    picture_data[] pics;
```

...

```
public class picture_data {

    static String filename;
    static String directory;
```

As you can see, I to have an array of picture_data in xmldata. I have seen some stuff using lists but the examples are different and I am not sure I understand how to apply it in my case.

Here's the code I used to try and populate the arrays.

```
    xmldata data = new xmldata();

    ResultSet pictures=db.query("select * from pictures where barcode=?",barcode);
    int i = -1;
    while (pictures.next()) {
        ++i;
        data.pics[i].setdirectory(pictures.getString("path"));
        data.pics[i].setfilename(pictures.getString("filename"));       
    }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Then dont use an array. Use an ArrayList or a Vector to store picture_data objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern [idiomatic](https://www.google.com/search?q=idomatic&aq=f&oq=idomatic&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3.4732j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&sa=X&q=idiomatic&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&ei=0CV8Ub-9EYHe8wTPtIHYCQ&ved=0CC0QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45645796,d.eWU&fp=8a6229a1b50653e4&biw=1686&bih=1031) Java doesn't use raw Arrays or Vector either, it uses [type safe `List` implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Also `picture_data` and `xmldata` are not idiomatic naming convention for classes in Java, it should be `PictureData` and `XMLData`. I would challenge the semantics of a class called `PictureData` or `XMLData` as well.

A correct solution would be something like

```
List<PictureData> list = new ArrayList<PictureData>();
```

Understanding how to work with the `Collections` framework in Java is a fundamental requirement to be productive. Type safe `List`s are a core component to writing real Java code.

Comment: This is doing something weird. I seem to be able to add to the list but when I pull values back out of the list they are always the last value I put into the list and not the correct values.

Answer (score 1):

If your array's size is going to be dynamic, then use lists inside and an `ArrayList` precisely. This way, you don't have to take care about size because it's treated internally.

Answer (score 1):

Create an object of picture_data and add it into a ArrayList of picture_data

Then convert that arraylist into an array

[Convert ArrayList<String> to String[] array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374311/convert-arrayliststring-to-string)

http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/how-to-convert-an-arraylist-into-an-array.html

Answer (score 0):

Best option would be to use **lazy** initialized `ArrayList`

```
public class Xmldata {

    List<picture_data> pics;

    public void addPics(picture_data data) {
       if(pics == null) pics = new ArrayList<picture_data>();
       pics.add(data);
    }
}
```

Here the `pics` list will only be created if the `picture_data` type objects are added to the `Xmldata` class

Comment: I'm assuming with this method I would need to create an instance of picture_data, add the data too it, and then add the instance to my XmlData instance.

Comment: Yes.. you need to create one instance.. in your `while` loop

Comment: This isn't working. I'm getting multiple entries of the same thing. The values in the list are wrong.