# ArrayList returning wrong value

Tags: java, arraylist

This is related to [Array of objects in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255832/array-of-objects-in-a-class). I originally added it on to that question but because that question was answered I wasn't getting responses.

So I have 2 classes. One containing a list of the other class. And I am adding data into the class that I have pulled out of the database. However when I go to pull the data back out of the List, values are all the same. They are the values of the last element in the list.

I have tried creating the object anew in each loop but it still seems to be causing a problem. I don't see what I am doing wrong here.

```
public class xmldata {
    String Barcode;
    String First;
    String Last;
    String Phone;
    String Email;

    String md5sum;

    String zipfile;

    List<PictureData> pics = new ArrayList<PictureData>();
```

...

```
public class PictureData {

    static String filename;
    static String directory;
```

...

```
xmldata data = new xmldata();

ResultSet pictures=db.query("select * from pictures where barcode=?",barcode);



while (pictures.next()) {
    PictureData pictemp= new PictureData();
    pictemp.setdirectory(pictures.getString("path"));
    pictemp.setfilename(pictures.getString("filename"));
    data.pics.add(pictemp);     
}
```

...

```
for (int j=0; j<data.pics.size();++j) {

    String path;
    PictureData pictemp2= new PictureData();

    pictemp2=(PictureData) data.pics.get(j);
    path=pictemp2.getdirectory()+pictemp2.getfilename();

    System.out.println(path);

    zip.addfile(path);

}
```

Comment: Have you breaked after your while to see the content in data.pics ?

Comment: It doesn't actually tell me what's in there. It just  lists pics>elementData>[0]PictureData(id=43) and pics>elementData>[1]PictureData(id=45)

Comment: Where is your PictureData?

Comment: @JermaineXu: check the previous post he has mentioned. Its there.

Comment: Sorry thought it was in what I copied.

Comment: You can remove this line : = new PictureData(); since you only need to create a new at the insert.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre, The secondary pictemp was just added as an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work if I remove that line Alexandre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
public class PictureData {

    static String filename;
    static String directory;

}
```

Why have you made filename and directory static? it can contain only one value. Make them non static and it will work.

Comment: So eventhough, I had multiple instances of the class, it could only hold one value because it was static and thus the same against all instances?

Comment: @Codeguy007: Yup , static is at class level not instance level.

Comment: I have the same problem and I also havent declared them static. not sure why