# Collection.toArray() method, detail about it

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, toarray

Why would not it work?

```
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        lista.add("Lol");
        lista.add("ball");
        String [] array = (String[])lista.toArray();
```

It throws a `RunTimeException (ClassCastException)`, I am aware that there is another method for the purpose of returning the object contained in the List, however what is happening behind the scenes? I mean I am casting an array of Objects which actually is an array of Strings to an Array of Strings. So it should compile, but it does not.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[List.toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29)
returns an `Object[]`, because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). At runtime your list does not know if it has String objects. From there you can see where that error is coming from.

You cannot type cast an `Object[]` into a `String[]`

Answer (score 4):

That version of toArray() returns `Object[]`. You can't cast an Object array into a String array even if all the objects in it are Strings.

You can use the `lista.toArray(new String[lista.size()]);` version to get the actual type correctly.

Comment: I am aware of it as I specified in the question. However I would like to know why. since using generics It's clear that it's an array of strings

Answer (score 0):

Array of objects is not array of Strings and **can't** be cast to one.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374311/convert-arrayliststring-to-string).

Answer (score 0):

use toArray(T[] a) instead.

Ie.

```
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
    lista.add("Lol");
    lista.add("ball");
    String [] array = lista.toArray(new string[1]);
```

This insures that toArray returns an array of type String[]

As others have noted, toArray() returns an array of type Object[], and the cast from Object[] to String[] is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

List lista = new ArrayList<>(); --->  List lista = new ArrayList();

Answer (score -2):

There are two toArray() versions.You can use another one!