# java List of Strings to Array of Strings

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, classcastexception

I want to know if it's possible to convert a Java `List` of `String`s to an array of `String`s:

I tried this:

```
List<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();
//some codes..
String[] arrayCategories = (String[]) products.toArray();
```

but it gives me an exception message:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]

Comment: @LalitPoptani The duplicate I've found is better :D

Comment: Duplicate is Duplicate better or worse :P

Comment: Problem here is not the Array conversion, but wrong use of [] on new ArrayList[String]() which should be new ArrayList<String>().. I was about to answer but you guys closed this..

Comment: hmmm. now that my edit is wrong, that is corrected. May it remain closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String[] array = products.toArray(new String[products.size()]);
```

Comment: it gaves me the same Exception

Comment: @MouadELFakir, then you might be doing something else wrong. Post your code to check what you are messing up

Comment: yeah thanks i just figured out what i was missig, i just forget to fill my products list i let it empty, it s working now just fine, thank u ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
String[] arrayCategories = products.toArray(new String[products.size()]);
```

`products.toArray()` will put list values in `Object[]` array, and same as you cant cast object of super type to its derived type like

```
//B extands A
B b = new A();
```

you can't store or cast `Object[]` array to `String[]` array so you need to pass array of exact type that you want to be returned.

Additional info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17909134/1393766).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
List<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] arrayCategories = products.toArray(new String[products.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. You got an typo in the first line.

```
List<String> products = new ArrayList<>();
String[] array = (String[]) products.toArray();
```