# How to get Array from Arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have the following data structure in Linear_Programming class .

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> constraint_temp  ;
ArrayList<Double> B_value_temp;
ArrayList<Double> obj_func ;
```

I want to pass this object to Simplex class constructor by the following code .

```
 Simplex smlpx = new Simplex(constraint_temp, B_value_temp,obj_func);
```

The prototype for constructor of Simplex method is as follows :

```
 public Simplex(double[][] A, double[] b, double[] c);
```

So I need a way to convert the arraylist to array . How can I do this ? Please suggest me a way .

Comment: why dont you use `toArray()` method?

Comment: I think main problem in first 2d array. Need some manual work.

Comment: It returns oject[] type . And what is the issue of 2d array ?

Comment: `toArray()` also has an overloaded method to accept the array and populate it, did you check it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert ArrayList<String> to String \[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374311/convert-arrayliststring-to-string)

Comment: Raedwald , Please look at the question . Help is needed because of 2d array .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, write a method to convert a `List<Double>` to a `double[]` -

```
private static double[] fromList(List<Double> al) {
  double[] out = new double[al.size()];
  for (int i = 0;i < al.size(); i++) {
    out[i] = al.get(i);
  }
  return out;
}
```

Then the complicated version is the two-dimensional argument `a`,

```
double[][] a = new double[constraint_temp.size()][];
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i] = fromList(constraint_temp.get(i));
}
double[] b = fromList(B_value_temp);
double[] c = fromList(obj_func);
Simplex smlpx = new Simplex(a,b,c);
```