# Using String.split on input file

Tags: java

So I have an input file of the form:

```
AdjGraphHeader
11
20
30
.
.
.
```

and I need to create a string array that holds each line separately. So I read the file using:

```
String s = FileUtils.readFileToString(f);
Words w = new Words(s, (long)s.length());
```

and then the words constructor did the following:

```
public Words(String str, long n_) {
    strings = str.split("\\n");
    string = str;
    n = n_;
    m = strings.length;
}
```

The issue seems to be that there is an extra line at the end of `adjGraphHeader`, but I have no idea how to get rid of it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your lines are separated not by `\n` but by `\r\n` so if you remove `\n` you still have `\r` after each word and while printing it you will see empty line. One of solutions could be splitting using this regular expression

`"\r?\n|\r"` - `?` makes element described before it optional, `|` represent "or" operator

which will handle line separators if forms `\r` `\r\n` `\n`.

You can also use something IMHO simpler like

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("locationOfFile"));
```

or if you already have `File f`

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(f.toPath());
```

and store each line in list (you can later [convert this list to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374311/convert-arrayliststring-to-string) if you really need it)