# Why I convert ArrayList to Interger[] is wrong?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, integer

```
private ArrayList<Integer> list;
...
...
...
for (int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                Log.e("downloadTask","resource ID is " + list.get(i));
            }
Integer[]  resourceId = resourceId= (Integer[])list.toArray();
```

before for() statement, list had already been initialized. It has three elements;
The Log message is right, but when run

```
Integer[]  resourceId = (Integer[]) list.toArray();
```

it will throw Exceptions. I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.toArray()` returns an array of objects (`Object[]`), which can not be cast to an integer array (because `Object[]` can contain anything, like `String`, `Boolean`, `SpiderMan`, not only `Integer`).

Try:

```
list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]); //will fill and return passed array 
                                        //with all elements from list
```

In the future, please provide the exact exceptions being thrown (and include the stack trace) so it's easier for people to spot the problem.

Comment: First ,thank you for your help.But I still don't know “new Integer[list.size()]” meaning. It means creating an new  Integer[3] array that copy from list ,yes or no?

Comment: That's correct, what the line `list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);` does is creating an array of integers with the list's size as its length, and pass that to the `toArray` method to fill. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T[]%29

Comment: I have already know the meaning from "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374311/convert-arrayliststring-to-string". Thank you again.