# How do I use List<String> for ArrayAdapter values (Java, Android)

Tags: android, listview, items

I'm trying to update listView items when application is running. I can make it work by using a String[] instead of List but my goal is make it work with List so I can add more items to listView while application is running.

```
private List<String> items;
```

I have made a List to MainActivity class.

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This doesn't work. I tried to hassle with items.ToArray(), but didn't found a solution. Tried Googling, but all results from Google redirects only to tutorials that shows how to make listView and every of tutorials were based on String[] array.

Application works fine if I use following:

```
private String[] items = {"Banana", "Lime"};
```

I want manage items real time when user adds them to list by using: "adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();"

I'm beginner on Java and especially about Android Developing so help is appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you initialized the arraylist, then your code should work. `adapter.add("hello")` would update the list without the need for `notifyDataSetChanged`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two approach to do this:

- Convert your List to Array (you can find a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5374359/1462770)).
- Create your own Adapter and use List ( another good example [here](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html)).

**First Approach**:

```
List<String> stockList = new ArrayList<String>();
stockList.add("stock1");
stockList.add("stock2");

String[] stockArr = new String[stockList.size()];
stockArr = stockList.toArray(stockArr);

for(String s : stockArr)
    System.out.println(s);
```

**Second Approach**:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{   

    String [] result;
    Context context;
    int [] imageId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result=prgmNameList;
        context=mainActivity;
        imageId=prgmImages;
         inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                 getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn. Didn't found such information through Google. I guess I am at so beginning so I didn't knew good enough keywords. Thanks Amir.

Comment: @WeirdE. If answers gives you enough information you can accept them.

Comment: Sure. Waiting for it. Site requires 5 minutes before I can accept it.

Comment: You could extend ArrayAdapter instead of BaseAdapter. Otherwise, you left out that you need to implement `getCount` and such

Comment: @cricket_007 yes you're right. I just paste some piece of code which is necessary 
¯\_(ツ)_/¯