# How to add prompt to spinner in Android

Tags: android, android-spinner

In my application I want use `Spinner` and for this a use this **library** : [MaterialSpinner](https://github.com/jaredrummler/MaterialSpinner)

How can I add `android:prompt` to this library?

please help me, I need this help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12221309/1976626

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can take a Look at this library:

[Material Spinner](https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner)

Use this dependency in your build.gradle file to reference this library in your project

```
compile 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1'
```

In the xml :

```
<fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        app:ms_multiline="false"
        app:ms_dropDownHintView="@layout/my_custom_dropdown_hint_item_layout"
        app:ms_hintView="@layout/my_custom_hint_item_layout""
        app:ms_hint="hint"       
        app:ms_enableFloatingLabel="false"
        app:ms_enableErrorLabel="false"
        app:ms_floatingLabelText="floating label"
        app:ms_baseColor="@color/base"
        app:ms_highlightColor="@color/highlight"
        app:ms_errorColor="@color/error"
        app:ms_typeface="typeface.ttf"
        app:ms_thickness="2dp"
        app:ms_hintColor="@color/hint"
        app:ms_arrowColor="@color/arrow"
        app:ms_arrowSize="16dp"
        app:ms_alignLabels="false"
        app:ms_floatingLabelColor="@color/floating_label"/>
```

You can set a hint and a floating label text. If no floating label text is provided, the hint will be set instead.

Comment: Thanks my friend, in my application I get data from server in List<>. such as this `response.body().getData()` in retrofit. but in your library I should add string[] for items. how can I convert i list to string[] ?  please help me

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374311/convert-arrayliststring-to-string-array