# Change ArrayList to Array

Tags: java, arrays

So I decided to use ArrayList but now I want to change it to Array.  I'm trying to see if this works with Array only instead of ArrayList. Can anyone sugest some way to do it nice and simple? I want to change it but I searched the internet for some way to do it but the information I found it didn't work for my case.

```
public class ProductManager {
    private List<Product> listOfProduct;
    public ProductManager() {
        this.listOfProduct= new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public int addProduct(Product p) {
        this.listOfProduct.add(p);
        return count();
    }

    public int count() {
        return this.listOfProduct.size();
    }

    public Product getProduct(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >=count()) {
            return null;
        }
        return this.listOfProduct.get(index);
    }

    public boolean removeProduct(int id) {
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0, n = count(); i < n;i++) {
            if(this.listOfProduct.get(i).getId() == id) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(index != -1) {
            this.listOfProduct.remove(index);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Some suggestions are appreciated :) Thank you!

Comment: Why change it to array? It's rarely necessary or smart to use arrays over collections.

Comment: 90% of the code you have posted seems to be completely unrelated to your problem. You may consider posting a [mcve] instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert ArrayList<String> to String\[\] array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374311/convert-arrayliststring-to-string-array)

Comment: Ok. So i will look over there for answers. Thank you.

Comment: You need to learn how to format your code. Indentation really helps with understanding what is executing and when. Both IntelliJ and Eclipse offer automatic formatting options (in the former, default Mac keybind is Command-Option-L and in the latter, you go to Save Actions under preferences).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like you're getting started with basic Java.

After reviewing your code, I'd like to share with you some points to improve.

First, look at your problem, the number of `Product` is dynamic, and you don't know exactly the number of how many `Product` to be added into the store, which is `ProductManager`. It means you should use a dynamic data structure, and your code uses `List`, this is correct. Only use array when you know exactly number of elements to allocate; otherwise, go for `List`.

To remove an element of `Collection`, which is `List` as in your code, it's better to use `Iterator`, in which you can remove element while looping. Here it is.

```
public Product removeProduct(int id) {
    Iterator<Product> iterator = productList.iterator();
    Product found = null;

    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        Product product = iterator.next();
        if(product.getId() == id) {
            found = product;
            iterator.remove(); // remove on the fly
        }
    }

    // return pointer to removed product
    // Note: it can be NULL
    return found;
}
```

For `removeProduct` method signature (return value), you can modify to return `boolean` value as you wish.

Instead of reading price value as string then parse to `Float` manually, you can directly use `scanner.nextFloat()` method. Read more about [Scanner here](https://kodemate.com/use-java-scanner-parse-content/).

To calculate the whole inventory price value, just loop and sum all the price.

```
public float getInventoryValue() {
    int total = productList.size();
    float sum = 0.0f;

    for(int i = 0; i < total; ++i) {
        // simple, easy loop
        sum += productList.get(i).getPrice();
    }

    return sum;
}
```

I guess that's done for your question.

If you insist on converting from `List` to array, you can either:

- Initialize a new static array with known size from `List.size()`, then assign elements.
- Or, quick dirty trick `Product[] productArr = (Product[]) productList.toArray();`

Last but not at least, you should write question and format code nicely; otherwise, others will vote down and close your questions :)

You're doing great, just a little more!

Comment: I'm not sure `productList.toArray()` will work, I think it would have to be `Product[] productArr= arrlist.toArray(new Product[productList.size()]);` or some such. `toArray(T[] a)` is the method, I don't think there's an option for no arguments (unless this is a new thing with Java 10 I'm not aware of). That said, good answer!

Comment: thank you guys! Appreciate your help and suggestions!

Comment: @GreyHaven you can refer to Java doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray--  , but it's not safe if it has some other references (pointer).

Comment: Oh, nice! Awesome, didn't realize that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out some java documentation, this is a pretty well known thing. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_toarray.htm

But a simple for loop would also do it.

```
Product[] convertArrayListToArray(ArrayList<Product> arrList){
    Product[] arr = new Product[arrList.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < arrList.size(); i++){
        arr[i] = arrList.get(i);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: If the types are guaranteed, you can just use `System.arraycopy`

Comment: Fair. I like the `toArray()` method a bit more just because it's a bit more intuitive of what's going on, fewer arguments etc. But yes, `arraycopy` is definitely legit.

Comment: But you don't use `toArray`, you're manually copying each element over.  Using `toArray` would look like this: `list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);`

Comment: Oh, yeah, totally. I was wanting to go over how to manually do it. Figured I'd let the link I provided speak for the `toArray(T[] a)` method.

Comment: thank you guys for the guidance! :) wish you all a nice day!