# Why does DefaultListModel.toArray() throw a ClassCastException?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to copy a `DefaultListModel` contents into an array. 
The following line causes the exception

> testArray = (cGenIndicator[]) indObjList.toArray();

```
void testCasting() {
    DefaultListModel<cGenIndicator> indObjList;
    indObjList = new DefaultListModel<cGenIndicator>();
    indObjList.addElement(new cGenIndicator(null, null));

    cGenIndicator[] testArray;
    try {
        // This line causses exception saying
        // [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LIndicator.cGenIndicator;
        testArray = (cGenIndicator[]) indObjList.toArray();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        test++;
    }

    test++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DefaultListModel.toArray` returns `Object[]`, and `Object[]` can not be casted to `cGenIndicator[]` directly.

You can achieve it this way:

```
Object[] objectArray = defaultListModel.toArray();
int length = objectArray.length;

cGenIndicator[] testArray = new cGenIndicator[length];
System.arraycopy(objects, 0, testArray, 0, length);
```

Answer (score 7):

`toArray`, without an argument, will return an `Object[]`, that can't be cast to a `cGenIndicator[]`. Instead, you can use the overloaded method that gets an array to fill as an argument:

```
testArray = indObjList.toArray(new cGenIndicator[indObjList.size()]);
```

**EDIT:**

`DefaultListModel` does not have this overloaded method, Mia Kulpa. One way to convert an `Object[]` to a `cGenIndicator` is with streams:

```
testArray = Arrays.stream(indObjList.toArray())
                  .map(cGenIndicator.class::cast)
                  .toArray(cGenIndicator[]::new)
```

Comment: it is a `DefaultListModel`, not an instance of a `List`

Answer (score 1):

The `DefaultModel::toArray()` method produces an `Object[]` not a `cGenIndicator[]`.

If this was a `List`, you would use `toArray(new cGenIndicator[0])` instead.
For more information, refer to the javadoc or to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5374346/139985.  Note that the latter talks about `String[]` but the principle is exactly the same.

For a `DefaultModelList` you do not have this option:

- The simple solution is to get rid of the type cast, and change to type of `testArray` to `Object[]`.
- You could also explicitly copy the elements of the `Object[]` to a more appropriately typed array.  Whether this is worthwhile will depend on how you are going to use the array.

---

<sup>And please fix your class / interface names to conform to the Java style rules.  `cGenIndicator` should be `CGenIndicator` ... or something more readable.</sup>