# How do I assign List<Project> to Project[ ] in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to initialize an array object with a get method which returns an arraylist object. I have tried using `.toArray()` to convert but it didn't work.

Comment: have you tried `.toArray(new Project[0])`?

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? Did you get a compile time error, a runtime error, a wrong result or something else? Be specific.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374311/convert-arrayliststring-to-string-array. basically the same thing except String and not Project Object

Answer (score 1):

Would `Project[] projects = list.toArray(new Project[[0]])` work? The reason it doesn't work normally is because by default `toArray` returns an `Object[]`, and the JVM is unable to cast that to a `Project[]`. Passing in the project array allows it to determine the type of the desired array.

Comment: you can even do `list.toArray(Project[]::new);`

Comment: Yes I noticed this question is a repetition but I understood it better when it was answered in my context, given that I'm also a newbie. I stopped getting the compile-time error when I passed an empty array (Project[0]) as an argument for the .toArray() method. i.e. According to my code, Project[ ] projects = list.toArray(new Project[0]);  Thank you all.