# Convert list of objects to array. Getting ArrayStoreException

Tags: java, collections

I do have such piece of code:

```
List<VersionedUserIdentifier> userIdentifiers = getUsersModule().getUsersIdentifiers();
if (userIdentifiers.isEmpty()) {
    LOG.info(No users to verify.");
    return;
}
VersionedUserIdentifier[] vIds = userIdentifiers.toArray(new VersionedUserIdentifier[0]);
```

I'm getting an error:

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException
at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:133)
```

I cannot convert list to array. Any ideas what could be wrong?
I have also tried:

```
VersionedUserIdentifier[] vIds = userIdentifiers.toArray(new VersionedUserIdentifier[userIdentifiers.size()]);
```

Comment: `new VersionedUserIdentifier[0]` can you explain this?

Comment: `LOG.info(No users to verify.");` correct this one too

Comment: Try this [Convert ArrayList<String> to String[] array [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374311/convert-arrayliststring-to-string-array) or [Converting 'ArrayList<String> to 'String\[\]' in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042434/converting-arrayliststring-to-string-in-java)

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo: The `new VersionedUserIdentifier[0]` is correct.

Comment: `toArray` is same as `toArray(new Object[0]) ` just read it. Thanks @Nikolas

Comment: @Maciaz Can you provide a complete example so that we can compile it and reproduce the error?

Comment: Unfortunatelly not. This is a part of bigger application. This was supposed to be just a simple ArrayList to Array convertion, but something goes wrong. `VersionedUserIdentifier` is a class with just 2 fields (id, version), standard getters, setters and constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This type of exception happens when you try to store different type of the object in the array.

Refer the below link
[Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html)

Comment: The object type is exactly the same.

Comment: Still I concur with Rutvik Joshi: `getUsersIdentifiers` probably uses untyped conversions and does not contain the same class `VersionedUserIdentifier`: `if (!userIdentifiers.stream().allMatch(vui -> vui instanceOf VersionedUserIdentifier)) { brrr }`. **Maybe the class was introduced in two different packages.**

Comment: if untyped conversion is done internally as @JoopEggen described above try to typecasting it like
VersionedUserIdentifier[] vIds = (VersionedUserIdentifier[]) userIdentifiers.toArray(new VersionedUserIdentifier[0]);

Answer (score -1):

This works for me..Please check

```
List<VersionedUserIdentifier> userIdentifiers = getUsersModule().getUsersIdentifiers();
VersionedUserIdentifier[] vui=(VersionedUserIdentifier[])userIdentifiers.toArray();
Stream.of(vui).forEach(System.out :: println);
```