# LinkedList to Array

Tags: java

I implemented a linkedList in Java and now I am working on a new method `toArray` in order to sort the link list after. I am getting an error when I am trying to print each elements of the ArrayList    Cannot resolve method 'toString(java.util.List)'

```
public class Node {
  int value;
  Node next;
}

public class LinkedList {
  Node head;

  public void toArray(LinkedList list){   
    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    Node iterator = head;

    while(iterator != null){
      temp.add(iterator.value);
      iterator = iterator.next;
    }

    temp.forEach(arr->System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp)));
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert ArrayList<String> to String\[\] array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374311/convert-arrayliststring-to-string-array)

Answer (score 2):

This expression is wrong:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp))
```

Because `temp` is an `ArrayList`, not an `Array`. Try this:

```
System.out.println(temp)
```

By the way, you still have some errors in your code, this should fix them:

```
public void toArray() {

    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();

    Node iterator = head;
    while (iterator != null) {
        temp.add(iterator.value);
        iterator = iterator.next;
    }

    temp.forEach(System.out::println);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method Arrays.toString() needs an Array in argument.
You need transform you List an one Array calling the method: **toArray()**.
Like this:

```java
temp.forEach(arr->System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp.toArray())));
```