# Converting ArrayList or Array to String Array

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm working on a project where i need to convert either an ArrayList or and Array to an String array.
I need each word/string to convert to seperate strings.

Something like this:

```
public ArrayList<String> arrList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and then convert it and past into

```
public String arrList4 [] = new String [250];
```

Hope this is detaild enough so you get what i want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert ArrayList containing Strings to an array of Strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042434/convert-arraylist-containing-strings-to-an-array-of-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    al.add("C");
    al.add("java2s.com");
    al.add("D");
    al.add("F");
    al.add(1, "java2s.com");

    String[] strings = al.toArray(new String[al.size()]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
```

Here is an interesting link: http://www.google.be/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ArrayList+to+array

Answer (score 1):

String []strArray = new String[250];
arrList2.toArray(strArray);