# How to copy elements from ArrayList to int Array in java

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert String arraylist to string array in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042434/convert-string-arraylist-to-string-array-in-java)

Following is my code

```
ArrayList<String> IdList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and I want to copy items from 
`IDList` to `int IdArray[]`.

Comment: int[] or String[] array?

Comment: Actually i want it int array. but String[] is also fine.

Comment: You should start with an ArrayList<int> in the first place if it doesn't matter XD

Comment: @ All: Thanks for your help.
Following code helped me out 
String[] array = Idlist.toArray(new String[list.size()]);

Answer (score 6):

Try this stuff,

```
     int arr[] = new int[arrList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrList.size(); i++) {
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(arrList.get(i));
        }
```

Comment: gave ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

Comment: int asize= IdList.size();
int arr[] = new int[asize];
        for (int i = 0; i < asize); i++) {
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(IdList.get(i));
        }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4261/discussion-between-soniya-and-lalit-poptani)

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> IdList = new ArrayList<String>();
int IdArray[].
    for (int i = 0; i < IdList.size(); i++) {
        IdArray[i] = (int)IdList.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must iterate through all items, which are Strings, and parse each of them into an int to populate your new int[] array.

Comment: Did you mean,
 Iterator itr = IdList.iterator(); 
    int IdArray[]={};
    int d=0;
    while(itr.hasNext()) 
    {
        String topic_id =  (String) itr.next(); 
        IdArray[d]= Integer.parseInt(topic_id);
        d++;
        System.out.print("============"+topic_id );
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
// String array
String[] arr = idList.toArray(new String[0]);
// for int array
int[] iarr = new int[arr.length];
int idx = 0;
for(String s : arr) {
   iarr[idx++] = Integer.parseInt(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String [] outStrArray = (String [])IdList.toArray()

Comment: This will throw a ClassCastException because `Collection.toArray()` returns a `Object[]`.

Answer (score -1):

```
int[] IdArray = IdList.toArray();
```

However, this will probably fail because you're trying to convert a string-arraylist to an int-array..