# Array after a loop

Tags: java, arrays

How can I make the result for this loop an array of the differents results:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= years; i++) {
    double newbalance = account.getBalance() * rate;
    account.deposit(newbalance);
    String test = String.valueOf(account.getBalance()) + "\n";
    result.append(test);
}
```

**For example**:

If the user put years `10`, that give me 10 results.

I need:

1. To put these 10 results in an array.
2. If the user eraser that input, an then press a specific button (I already have the code), the data need to be deleted and calculate with the new values.

Thank you.

Comment: You are already appending in a container called result. Do you want to copy these values to another array?

Comment: yes I need that ? @VidorVistrom

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929321/converting-arraylist-to-array-in-java

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] result = new String[years];

for (int i = 1; i <= years; i++) {
    double newbalance = account.getBalance() * rate;
    account.deposit(newbalance);
    String test = String.valueOf(account.getBalance());
    result[i-1]  = test;
}
```

If you want the data to be deleted from the result, you can initialize result again:

```
result = new String[years];
```

Comment: `i` starts at 1, so you have the use `i-1` to set the value in `result`

Comment: why you put the years inside the String array?

Comment: Put years inside string array because since we already know the year, I use this year value to create a size of year value of string array. If your years is 10, it will create a size of 10's string array.