# changing arraylist to array in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am a beginner. Can you please help me identify the mistake in the following program ?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     ArrayList li = new ArrayList<>();
     li.add(1);
     li.add(2);
     li.add(3);

     System.out.println(li.get(1));

     int arr[] = new int[li.size()];
     for(int i=0; i<li.size(); i++)
     {
         arr[i] = li.get(i);
     }

     for(int item:arr)
     System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

While executing the above program, I get the following error :

```
Main.java:23: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to int
     arr[i] = li.get(i);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting ArrayList to Array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929321/converting-arraylist-to-array-in-java)

Comment: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: li is a list of strings, you have to use casting to make it into an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using raw ArrayList, so it contains `Objects` instead of `Integers`. You can't assign `Object` type to `int` type, hence you get the error when you try to save an `Object` type into `int`array.

Pass a generic type argument to `ArrayList` so that compiler knows that `li` is an `ArrayList` that contains `Integers`.

Change

```
ArrayList li = new ArrayList<>();
```

to

```
ArrayList<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You've not given the type for ArrayList in the declaration. So, that would be equivalent to `ArrayList<Object>`, meaning that any type of object can be added to arraylist. There are two ways you can fix this.

**1. Declare the type in arraylist declaration.**

```
ArrayList<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>();
```

**2. Cast the object that that you fetch from list to an int type**

```
for(int i=0; i<li.size(); i++)
   {
       arr[i] = (int)li.get(i);
   }
```