# java - Convert String ArrayList to String Array with bigger size

Tags: java, arraylist, arrays

I am trying to convert Array list to String array but getting an exception. Can somebody please help me.

**Size of ArrayList: 1

Size of String Array: 2**

I am using the following code:

```
String[] StringArray ={};
StringArray = ArrayList.toArray(new String[ArrayList.size()]);
```

So, the length of `StringArray` now is 1. But it should be 2. **My problem is how can i convert arraylist to StringArray if String Array size is more than the ArrayList.**

How can i do that? Please guys help me.

Comment: That would not compile: `toArray` is not a static method of the `ArrayList` class. Is that your real code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert String arraylist to string array in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042434/convert-string-arraylist-to-string-array-in-java)

Comment: I think, that there is no statis call... he just named variables ArrayList and StringArray

Comment: no, its not a duplicate of the question linked. My problem is how can i convert arraylist to StringArray if String Array size is more than the ArrayList. Guys please help me.

Comment: @rockskull please see my comment above

Comment: @Aʌɐpɥɐuı Show all the relevant code (how you create the list, how you determine the sizes etc.).

Comment: Old StringArray size is ommited in moment, you make "=" from toArray

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check

Comment: @Aʌɐpɥɐuı With the code you show, StringArray should be the same size as `nameValuesTestImage` at the end.

Comment: bad naming conventions. Variable names should not start with capitals unless your looking to confuse reviewers and helpers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to convert `ArrayList` to a bigger `String` array, use `toArray()` and pass the array you want to fill as parameter. If the array size is more than needed, the rest of the elements will be `null`. If the array is smaller - a new array will be returned with size as `list.size`.

All taken from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)

```
ArrayList<String> list  = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("abc");

String[] StringArray = new String[2];
StringArray = list.toArray(StringArray);
```

In that case, even though the list size is 1, `StringArray` is of size 2, adding null values at the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String[] arr = new String[list.size()];
 arr = list.toArray(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like in this tutorial: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/convert-arraylist-to-arrays-in-java/

The size of array defined before `.toArray` method has no effect on result. After calling `.toArray`, old array is destroyed by JVM.

Answer (score 0):

If we pass an array as argument to method `toArray` then it populates that with the items of list else it returns an array of `Object`. We can pass an array of size larger than the list as argument to get an array of greater size. The following example explains it:

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<String> list  = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("One");
        System.out.println("list Size: " + list.size());

        //If we pass an array as argument it will be filled with items from list and then returned. Here array size is (list.size +2 )
        String[] stringArray = list.toArray(new String[2]);
        System.out.println("stringArray Size: " + stringArray.length);

        //If we do not pass an array as argument we get Object[] of same size
        Object[] objects = list.toArray();
        System.out.println("objects Size: " + objects.length);

        // Java 8 has option of streams to get same size array
        String[] stringArrayUsingStream = list.stream().toArray(String[]::new);
        System.out.println("stringArrayUsingStream Size: " + stringArrayUsingStream.length);
    }
```

As shown above we have an option of using streams also in Java 8. The output is:

`list Size: 1
stringArray Size: 2
objects Size: 1
stringArrayUsingStream Size: 1`