# Using 0 size array as parameter of List.toArray<T[]>

Tags: java

I was wondering, which is a recommended way to convert list to array, as both methods just seems to work fine.

As from [Converting 'ArrayList<String> to 'String[]' in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042434/convert-string-arraylist-to-string-array-in-java), I saw `new String[list.size()]` way is recommend, but I'm not sure why.

```
list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

---

```
list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass an array of size 0, `toArray()` will need to use reflection to create a new array instance of the same type.
That is slow.

If you pass a correctly-sized array, it can simply use the array instance that you passed, so it won't need to do any extra work.

Comment: Why does it need to use reflection to allocate an array of the right size?  Wouldn't it just run the same code that Cheok's got in his second line?

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot Cheok's code is specialized for the case of a String array. toArray() has to create a correctly sized array of the same type as its argument, whatever that is.

Comment: Why reflection, generic type cast will do perfectly? I can't see why reflection is required, I think you're mistaking.

Comment: @MouseEvent: You're forgetting about type erasure.  That isn't possible.

Comment: Interesting. Java IDE IntelliJ IDEA has a code inspection that will helpfully recommend this. It doesn't explain why it suggests it though.