# Java complains about incompatible types when using same type

Tags: java

I tried looking around some around here and on Google, but unfortunatly found nothing.

Here is my code:

```
class DeleteLists
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TokenAuth auth = new TokenAuth("xxxxx", "xxxxx");
        JKippt jkippt = new JKippt(auth);

            ClipList[] lists = jkippt.getLists();

            for (int i = 0; i <= lists.length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (lists[i].isPrivate() == false);
                {
                    {System.out.println(lists[i].getTitle);
                    jkippt.deleteList(lists[i].getId());
                }
            }
    }
}
```

When I try compiling it, it outputs this:

```
DeleteLists.java:18: error: incompatible types
        ClipList[] lists = jkippt.getLists();
                                  ^
    required: ClipList[]
    found:    Iterator<ClipList>
```

This could very possibly be a very basic mistake, but what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you very much in advance!
    Eden.

Comment: what does your getLists() return

Comment: Please post JKippt class code

Comment: My JVM doesn't have `TokenAuth` `JKippt` `ClipList` classes. Where can I find them? If you are creator of these classes you should included their code so we could easier find solution, or eventually suggest improvements/corrections.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This method returns an `Iterator`:

```
Iterator<ClipList> it = jkippt.getLists();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  ClipList clipList = it.next();
  // do stuff with clipList
}
```

Deciding to return an `Iterator` from an API method (particularly one named `getLists()`) is a strange decision, it would be better if it returned a `List` or a `Collection` (or at least a `Iterable`). If that where the case, you *could* use it like this:

```
for (ClipList clipList : jkippt.getLists()) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I've used the Iterator because the service is returning back a paged result. In the background the ClipList iterator iterate over an iterator of result pages. 

Returning a List or a Collection was not possible unless getting all the result pages in one method call.

The Iterable could be a solution but this solution can hide resource allocation to the user (requiring result page through http).

The method name is from the Kippt service endpoint, I admit it is ugly .

Answer (score 1):

The `getLists()` method returns an `Iterator` of `ClipList` elements.
There are more examples in the library project page: https://code.google.com/p/jkippt/

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the library.

Answer (score 0):

The method returns an Iterator, not an array. To go over the elements of an iterator you can use the while loop:

```
Iterator<ClipList> iter = jkippt.getLists();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    ClipList list = iter.next();
    ...
}
```

Comment: sorry, but isn't for-each working with `Iterable` not `Iterator`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an `Iterator` loop:

```
for (Iterator<ClipList> i = jkippt.getLists(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    ClipList list = i.next();
    if (!list.isPrivate()) {
        System.out.println(list.getTitle);
        i.remove();
    }
}
```

Note that you have a bug in your code - there is an errant semicolon after your `if`, which has the effect of making the `if` statement have an empty block.

Also, this line of yours will probably throw an `ConcurrentModificationException`:

```
jkippt.deleteList(list.getId());
```

so I changed it to the proper way to delete using an iterator via the `remove()` method.

Also note the change here to using `if (!list.isPrivate())` rather than your `if (list.isPrivate() == false)`, which is unnecessarily cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

As said, getLists() returns an iterator. You can convert it to an arraylist with the following code sample:

```
Iterator<String> lists = jkippt.getLists();
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
while (list.hasNext())
  result.add(list.next());
```

Here `result` is your arraylist. If you want to convert it to an array I suggest you visit the topic [ArrayList to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042434/convert-string-arraylist-to-string-array-in-java)