# Another way to convert ArrayList containing Strings to an array of Strings in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, type-conversion

I have checked the following stackoverflow source to solve my problem:

[StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042434/convert-arraylist-containing-strings-to-an-array-of-strings-in-java)

but, when applying the top solution, I still get an error, as follows:

My list is defined here:

```
List linhaInicial = new ArrayList();
```

My convertion is made here:

```
String[] convertido = linhaInicial.toArray(new String[linhaInicial.size()]);
```

The problem is I still get the following error:

```
Error:(86, 59) java: incompatible types
required: java.lang.String[]
found:    java.lang.Object[]
```

My conversion is somehow still returning `Object[]` when it should now be returning `String[]`.

Any solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: You know that compiler warning you ignored? The one about raw types? Maybe you shouldn't have ignored it...

Comment: Also do not use `linhaInicial.toArray(new String[linhaInicial.size()]);` just `linhaInicial.toArray(new String[]);`

Comment: Why this, Eypros?
On the other topic, somebody said that sending the correct size saves one instantiation, isnt's it correct?

Comment: @Allison: You are completely right. Eypros' code doesn't even compile and is not a good suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use [raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)!

```
List linhaInicial = new ArrayList();
```

should be

```
List<String> linhaInicial = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Change :

```
List linhaInicial = new ArrayList(); // can contain any Object. 
             //So compiler throws an error while converting an Object to String.
```

to

```
List<String> linhaInicial = new ArrayList<String>(); // using Generics ensures
                          //that your List can contain only Strings, so, compiler
                            //will not throw "incompatible types" error
```

Answer (score 1):

Always try to include the type of the list element in your declaration:

```
List<String> linhaInicial = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Avoid raw types as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change

```
List linhaInicial = new ArrayList(); // you are using raw type List
```

To

```
List<String> linhaInicial = new ArrayList();// you have to use String type List
```