# ArrayList object to separate Array conversion

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm stuck on this problem i make a class `Person` in which it has only two properties name and age. I'm taking details of that person as a user input and saving as a object in `ArrayList` but i want to move that `ArrayList` object properties that user enter from keyboard into separate arrays like all names of person into `String` array and all ages of person into `int` array from that ArrayList. Is there a way to do that?
Code:

```
public class Person {

    String name;
    int age;

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Person> arr = new ArrayList<Person>();
        Person person = null;



        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            person = new Person();
            System.out.println("Enter Person "+(i+1)+" Record");
            int age = 0;
            System.out.print("Enter Name : ");
            String str = s.nextLine();
            person.name = str;
            System.out.print("Enter Age : ");
            age = s.nextInt();
            s.nextLine();
            person.age = age;
            arr.add(person);
            person = null;
            System.out.println("Record "+(i+1)+" Successful Fill");

        }
            String[] stringarray = new String[arr.size()];
            int[] intarray = new int[arr.size()];

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hold your arraylist with person-objects and fill the arrays after all values read in create a new function:

```
private void add2Arrays(List<Person> list) {
  for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Person p = list.get(i);
    stringarray[i] = p.getName();
    intarray[i] = p.getAge();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this.  One would be to create `ArrayLists` instead for ages and names and add to them each time new values are pulled in.

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<int> ages = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    // create person object
    names.add(str);
    ages.add(age);
}
```

And if they absolutely NEED to be `Arrays` then you can convert with:

```
String[] nameArray = names.toArray(new String[0]);
String[] ageArray = ages.toArray(new int[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any fancy ways to go about doing this, but a way to do it, whenever you need them, is make a method to loop through all Person objects and make two arrays of the information.

So...

```
int[] ages = new int[arr.size()];
String[] names = new String[arr.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++){
     //assign attributes
}
```

Then do whatever you want with these arrays...

Again, there may be a better way to do it, but this will definitel work, although it is not too efficient.

---

However,
in your for loop, right where you add the Person objects to the array, you can just add them to a declared arraylist in the beginning.

Then if you truly need it to be a "List" as opposed to "ArrayList",
you can convert the arraylist to a list. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042434/converting-arrayliststring-to-string-in-java) is a good example of that.