# PrintWriter ignores sent lines except the last line

Tags: java, logging, swingworker, filewriter, printwriter

I wrote a Java Swing program which listens at the serial port (I use [JSerialComm library](http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/)). The program should display the received data in the console (works already), in a textarea-field (works, too) and in a file (does not work).

The receiving process starts by pressing on a button and end by pressing on another button.

I use the *SwingWorker* class to put GUI changes in the event dispatch thread. The configuration, opening and reading from the serial port happens in the `doInBackground()` method. The reading is an endless while-loop which is embedded in another while-loop who tests for `isCancelled()`. The cancel action is triggert by pressing on a button in the GUI.

The output in the textarea and the console takes place in the `process()` method. The `done()` method just do some enabling/disabling GUI elements and stores the PrintWriter `close()` method.

For writing in the file I use a FileWriter/PrintWriter (in `process()` method).

**The result:** I get the last sent line in the file. The previos sent line are ignored (in the file only). E.g. I send "one" "two" "three" through the serial connection via terminal program (line end = LF, CR or CR-LF makes no difference). I just receive the line "three" in the file. On the GUI and console I received the complete 3 strings as expected.

My relevant shortened code (Whole code at [GitHub](https://github.com/haniibrahim/SerialLogger/blob/732d023a9bb6044ff6f73340527845e95e43270c/de/haniibrahim/serialprinter/SerialPrinter.java), branch "logfile"):

```
public class SerialPrinter extends JFrame {

    PrintWriter pw;

    private class SerialReadTask extends SwingWorker<Boolean, String> {
        protected Boolean doInBackground() {
            // [Omitted code] Get values from the GUI an open serial port ....
            // Reading serial data
            Scanner serialScanner = new Scanner(chosenPort.getInputStream());
            while (!isCancelled()) {
                while (serialScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = serialScanner.nextLine();
                    publish(line);
                }
            }
            return false; // Returns true if cannot open serial port (code not here)
        }

        protected void process(List<String> chunk) {
            try {
                pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tf_Logfile.getText()));
                for (String line : chunk) {
                    pw.println(line); // save to file
                    ta_VirtualPrint.append(line + "\n"); // display in GUI => WORKS!!!
                    System.out.println(line); // print on console => WORKS!!!
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }

        protected void done() {
            // [Omitted code] Disabling some GUI elemts. Usage of get()<Boolean>    
            if (pw != null) { // if PrintWriter bw exists
                pw.close(); // Close but just get the last submitted line in the file
            }
        }

        private void btn_OpenPortActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) [
            serialReader.execute()
        }

        private void btn_ClosePortActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) [
            serialReader.cancel()
        }
}
```

Hope you have an idea. Thank you in advance,

Hani

Comment: You should invoke pw.flush() after writing or before closing or alternatively use a BufferedWriter (which auto-flushes on close) to make sure the content is actually written into the stream

Comment: You could also pass `true` to the constructor after you're `FileWriter` to do automatic flushing when you call `println`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `publish` for each line :

```
publish(line);
```

So each time the file is overwritten with a single line, and you end up with the last read line written.

You may consider populating a `List<String>` will all read lines, then [convert the list to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042434/converting-arrayliststring-to-string-in-java), and call `publish` with this array.

```
    while (!isCancelled()) {

        List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (serialScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = serialScanner.nextLine();
            data.add(line);
        }

        publish(data.toArray(new String[data.size()]));
    }
```

Alternatively you may keep your code as is, and just create your `FileWriter` in **append** mode :

```
pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tf_Logfile.getText(), true));
```

Comment: You was to fast. I will do it. Please do not consider my answer below so far regarding your post.

Comment: As I mentioned to Jorn. That does not the job. It t appends the last line of each program run in the file. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I put the File/PrintWriter in the background task instead of the EDT (progress()) task, see code below. Added lines are marked with `// NEW`:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground() throws IOException { // NEW Exception 
            // [Omitted code] Get values from the GUI an open serial port ....
            // Reading serial data
            pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tf_Logfile.getText())); // NEW
            Scanner serialScanner = new Scanner(chosenPort.getInputStream());
            while (!isCancelled()) {
                while (serialScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = serialScanner.nextLine();
                    publish(line);
                    pw.println(line); // NEW
                }
            }
            return false; // Returns true if cannot open serial port (code not here)
        }
```

The `pw.close()` happens still in the `done()` method.

Anyway, as I mentioned before this looks more or less as an workaround, because I haven't understood why the first approach does not work for files but for screen output.

Anyway, after som refactoring => [GitHub](https://github.com/haniibrahim/SerialLogger)