# How can I pass List<String> as an Intent extra?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, parse-platform

I have a List that I want to convert into a String[] so that I can pass it as an extra with an intent.

```
List<String> votedBy = parseObject.getList("votedBy");
```

The intent logic:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CommentActivity.this, UsersListActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(BundleConstants.KEY_LIST_TYPE, getString(R.string.voters));
intent.putExtra(BundleConstants.KEY_VOTERS_LIST, votedBy);
startActivity(intent);
```

My first thought was to convert the contents of the List to a String[], but that list is retrieved from a database and its size is not known apriori. One suggestion I had was to cast the votedBy List as Parcelable. I can't run the code at the moment so I'm not sure if that will work. What should I do here?

Comment: FYI: String is parcelable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is used to send using intent from one activity.

```
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("votedBy",new ArrayList<>(votedBy));
```

To receive this can be used;

```
ArrayList<String> votedByList= getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("votedBy");
```

Comment: And retrieve with ``bundle.getIntArray("BundleConstants.KEY_VOTERS_LIST")`` I take it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, a List cannot be passed as an Intent extra.

I would suggest to pass the original String as was retrieved from the database, then parse it directly at the new activity (UserListActivity).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try with

```
List<String> list = ..;
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042434/converting-arrayliststring-to-string-in-java).
As you can see, the size of the list is never a problem for the conversion, you never need to know it.