# How can I set a list of strings that were generated from a loop, into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, methods

```
public static String[] findWordsOfLength(String letters, int wordSize) {
    letters = "fourgooddogsswam";
    for(int i = 0; i < letters.length()-3;i++){
        String fourLetter = letters.substring(i,i+4);
    }
   for(int i = 0; i < letters.length()-4;i++){
        String fiveLetter = letters.substring(i,i+5);
    }

    return ?;
}
```

I was wondering if I could somehow set the list of strings generated from this loop, into a string array? Is there a way I could return that value if I used multiple loops for different strings?

Comment: Use an ArrayList class, and then convert to Array after if necessary. Unless you work out the length of the Array first

Comment: Or don't even convert to an array, and return the list directly.

Comment: Is there a way of doing it without ArrayList?

Comment: Billy. Maybe. But what is this code supposed to do in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

As [Scary Wombat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310289/scary-wombat) suggested in the comments, in the beginning of the method, [you can create an ArrayList](https://ideone.com/0w3tKG). Then within in each loop iteration, you can just keep adding to it. At the end of the method, you can convert the list to an array using the [toArray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4042464/4297364) method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Example {

    public static String[] findWordsOfLength(String letters, int wordSize) {
        if(letters == null) {
            return null;
        }

        int size = letters.length();
        int wordMax = size - wordSize + 1;
        if(size < wordMax || wordMax <= 0) {
            return new String[0];
        }

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < wordMax; i++) {
            result.add(letters.substring(i, i + wordSize));
        }

        return result.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] word = findWordsOfLength("fourgooddogsswam", 4);

        for(String word : words) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }

        /**
        * Output in console:
        *
        * four
        * ourg
        * urgo
        * rgoo
        * good
        * oodd
        * oddo
        * ddog
        * dogs
        * ogss
        * gssw
        * sswa
        * swam
        */
    }
}
```

Note that the advantage of using a list is that you don't need to know its size in advance. An array, on other hand, is initialized with a set size.

If you must use an array, [you could do](https://ideone.com/f8vOCR):

```
public static String[] findWordsOfLength(String letters, int wordSize) {
    if(letters == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int size = letters.length();
    int wordMax = size - wordSize + 1;
    if(size < wordMax || wordMax <= 0) {
        return new String[0];
    }

    int j = 0;
    String[] result = new String[wordMax];

    for (int i = 0; i < wordMax; i++) {
        result[j ++] = letters.substring(i, i + wordSize);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I hate to ask but could you be more specefic? How would I use an ArrayList in this circumstance? thanks

Comment: Is there a way do do it without using array list?

Comment: @Billy The advantage of a list is that it will grow as you add items to it. An array, on other hand, has a definitive size, determined when initialized. Although, in this particular case, it seems you would know the size of array.

Comment: Yes but I'm not allowed to use ArrayLists, how else would I be able to do this?

Comment: @Billy I've added a second solution using just an array.

Comment: Is there a way I can set the fourgooddogsswam so that it shifts right by one character and sets the four characters to an array? So the result would be:four ourg urgo rgoo good oodd oddo ddog dogs ogss gssw sswa swam

Comment: @Billy yes just call the `findWordsOfLength` method with whatever string and word count you want. I've updated the answer to use your example. You can also run it online [here](https://ideone.com/f8vOCR).

Answer (score 0):

Here´s an answer not involving a `List`.

Based on the input you can precalculate the output length of your array and initialize it with the given size. Than you´d just be looping over the array size and use mathematics again to substring from the input.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] words = findWordsOfLength("fourgooddogsswam", 4);
    print(words);
}

public static String[] findWordsOfLength(String letters, int wordSize) {
    // your working and output array definition
    String[] words;
    // If not even dividable add one to the size
    if (letters.length() % wordSize == 0) {
        words = new String[letters.length() / wordSize];
    } else {
        words = new String[letters.length() / wordSize + 1];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length;i++){
        // To not run into IndexOutOfBound check if we´d be going out of bound
        if(i*wordSize + wordSize > letters.length()) {
            words[i] = letters.substring(i*wordSize);
        } else {
            words[i] = letters.substring(i*wordSize, i*wordSize+wordSize);
        }
    }
    return words;
} 

// Just prints
public static void print(String[] input) {
    for(String string : input) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

O/P:

```
four
good
dogs
swam
```