# The method addAll(Collection<? extends Object[]>) in the type List<Object[]> is not applicable for the arguments (List<String>)

Tags: java, collections

I succeed to have the list of months between two dates and now I want to add this list to another list of Object, I used `addAll` but I had this error :
`The method addAll(Collection<? extends Object[]>) in the type List<Object[]> is not applicable for the arguments (List<String>)`

This is my attempt :

```
public void nbreRep(ActionEvent e){
List<Object[]> results;  
List<String>dateObj=new ArrayList<String>() ; 
Date date_de;
Date date_a;
Calendar beginCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar finishCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginCalendar.setTime(date_de);
    finishCalendar.setTime(date_a);
    while (beginCalendar.before(finishCalendar)) {

        Date datediff = beginCalendar.getTime();
        beginCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
         fC = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar fCa = Calendar.getInstance();
        fC.setTime(datediff);
        fCa.setTime(datediff);
        int year = fCa.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        String d=fC.getDisplayName(fC.MONTH, fC.LONG, Locale.FRANCE )+" "+year;
 dateObj.add(d);
    } 
    Query query=entityManager.createQuery("select r.dateheurerep,count(r) as nbrr "+"  from Reparation r where r.dateheurerep >= :date_de and r.dateheurerep <= :date_a GROUP BY YEAR(r.dateheurerep),MONTH(r.dateheurerep)");
    query.setParameter("date_de", date_de);
    query.setParameter("date_a", date_a);
    results = query.getResultList( );
    results.addAll(dateObj);
 }
```

Comment: A String is not an Array of Objects. What are you actually trying to acomplish and how would the conversion from String to Object[] work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your object added to dateObj should be a date and a count `List<Object[]>dateObj=new ArrayList<Object[]>() ;`

```
public void nbreRep(ActionEvent e){
List<Object[]> results;  
List<Object[]>dateObj=new ArrayList<Object[]>() ; 
Date date_de;
Date date_a;
Calendar beginCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar finishCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginCalendar.setTime(date_de);
    finishCalendar.setTime(date_a);
    while (beginCalendar.before(finishCalendar)) {

        Date datediff = beginCalendar.getTime();
        beginCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
         fC = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar fCa = Calendar.getInstance();
        fC.setTime(datediff);
        fCa.setTime(datediff);
        int year = fCa.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        String d=fC.getDisplayName(fC.MONTH, fC.LONG, Locale.FRANCE )+" "+year;
        Object[] obj = new Object[2];
        obj[0] = d;
        obj[1] = 1;
 dateObj.add(obj);
    } 
    Query query=entityManager.createQuery("select r.dateheurerep,count(r) as nbrr "+"  from Reparation r where r.dateheurerep >= :date_de and r.dateheurerep <= :date_a GROUP BY YEAR(r.dateheurerep),MONTH(r.dateheurerep)");
    query.setParameter("date_de", date_de);
    query.setParameter("date_a", date_a);
    results = query.getResultList( );
    results.addAll(dateObj);
 }
```

Comment: I have a month repeated in the lists `results` and `dateObj`,I should remove the repeated element from `dateObj`, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
List<Object[]> results; 
        to 
List<Object> results;
```

or Change

```
List<String> dateObj = new ArrayList<String>();
        to
List<Character[]> dateObj = new ArrayList<>();

and then to add elements to dateObj, use
dateObj.add(d.toCharArray());
```

Your results list expects array of objects as its elements. String is not an array of object, it is just an object. First method specifies that results list is expecting objects as its elements. Second method ensures that you pass an array of objects to results. Your choice, use whichever suites your need.

Answer (score 0):

Your `result` variable has the type "List of arrays of Objects".

Your `dateObj` variable has the type "List of Strings".

In Java, `List` and `array` (`[]`) are entirely different constructs, which are not compatible with one another. This is exactly what the error message you cite says.

A way to solve your issue is to convert your `dateObj` list to an array prior to adding it to `result` ([see this StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042434/converting-arrayliststring-to-string-in-java)).

---

Note however that it may not be enough for your code to work, depending on the actual object returned by `query.getResultList()`. It may be unmodifiable, in which case it will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.