# javax.faces.FacesException: Value of must be an array or a collection

Tags: jsf, selectmanymenu

I am getting the error:

> javax.faces.FacesException: Value of 'frmrapport:type' must be an array or a collection

from the XHTML file:

```
<p:selectManyMenu id="type" required="true"
        value="#{userReporting.getTypeParId(userReporting.selected)[0].nomType}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="co" itemValue="co" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="pi" itemValue="pi" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="si" itemValue="si" />
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

from the Java bean:

```
public List getTypeParId(int id){
    return this.genTypeFacade.getTypeParId(id);
}
```

the problem is that the bean is a `List` and I can't convert the list to a `String[]`.

Comment: If the question is "How do I convert List<String> to String[]", it's a duplicate **and** extremely easy to find on internet and SO. But I believe that's not your real problem.

Answer (score -1):

`userReporting.getTypeParId(userReporting.selected)` is returning a `List`. You can't access `List[0]`, you must use `List#get(int index)`.

```
value="#{userReporting.getTypeParId(userReporting.selected).get(0).nomType}"
```

Also, be carefult with generics: it's better if you specify what contains the collection you return, i.e.:

```
public List<Type> getTypeParId(int id){
     return this.genTypeFacade.getTypeParId(id);
}
```

Another "also": Your method `getTypeParId` returns more than 1 type? If yes, it should be called `getTypesParId`.

Comment: Your answer is correcterer than mine, I better remove my answer.

Comment: @hamena314 You could've let it, as it answered the question of TO; not the problem, but the question :p

Comment: javax.faces.FacesException: Value of 'frmrapport:type' must be an array or a collection

Comment: @MohamedNani That's an exception, indeed. Maybe you wanted to wrap it in a sentence? :p If you have troubles in english, you can explain it in french in the comments (of this answer) and I'll update your question.

Comment: selectManyMenu accepte String[] or collection only but my method is list i want solution to convert result of list to String[]

Comment: @Nathan: I dont want to answer the question of the TO, I want to help him. This is a big difference if it means that I need to answer questions of the TO he has not even asked. And in that case your answer is probably much closer to what TO needs help with. :)

Comment: @MohamedNani First of all, if it accepts a `Collection`, your list is ok: the problem is that you're trying to take it's first element ([0]). Then, if you really want to convert your list to an array, you can look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042434/converting-arrayliststring-to-string-in-java) that explains it.

Comment: @hamena314 Well it seems he really wants a List, so I'm gonna flag it back as a duplicate :p

Comment: @Nathan i try get(0) but the same problem , i want convert result of list to string[]

Comment: @Nathan i try this `       public String[] getTypeParId(int id){
                 String[] stringArray;
stringArray = (String[]) this.genTypeFacade.getTypeParId(id).toArray(new String[0]);

    return stringArray;
} 
` the error 
Grave:   java.lang.ArrayStoreException