# How to cast List to String[] in Android

Tags: android, arrays, list

In my application I want use ChipView, from this Library : https://github.com/adroitandroid/ChipCloud
In this library for set lists , I should use string[].
In my application I get lists of Tag with this code :

```
response.body().getData().getTags()
```

And Tags model is :

```
@SerializedName("tags")
@Expose
private List<NewsDetailTag> tags = null;
...
public List<NewsDetailTag> getTags() {
    return tags;
}
```

In above library I should add list with this codes :

```
chipCloud.addChips(someStringArray);
```

How can I convert List to string[] in android?

Please help me guys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert list to array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572795/convert-list-to-array-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a "conversion" at all! No need to waste memory :)

Take a look at the code of the library and see, what `ChipCloud.addChips()` does:

```
public void addChips(String[] labels) {
    for (String label : labels) {
        addChip(label);
    }
}
```

Its just going through the elements of the array and adding each string individually with the `addChip()` method.

In your code, you can do this the same way with a list:

```
List<NewsDetailTag> tags;
String              tagString;
ChipCloud           chipCloud;

// Get the tags, initialize the chipCloud, etc ...

for (NewsDetailTag tag : tags) {
    tagString = tag.getTheStringFromNewsDetailTag();
    chipCloud.addChip(tagString);
}
```

You could even write your own class that extends `ChipCloud` and add a method that accepts a `List` parameter.

The only thing thats left to do is to get a `String` from your `NewsDetailTag`s. But it looks like they are serializable anyways.

Comment: Thanks my friend, when use your code show me this error : `void com.adroitandroid.chipcloud.ChipCloud.addChip(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference` for this line : `chipCloud.addChip(tagString);` . but when use this line : `Log.e("Tag", tag.getName())` show me all tags from server! Why not set into `chipCloud.addChip(tagString);
`  ?

Comment: can you help me my friend?

Comment: Your `ChipCloud` reference is `null`. You can't invoke methods on a null reference. When you defined the chipcloud in an xml layout you can use `ChipCloud chipCloud = (ChipCloud) this.findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_your_chipcloud);` to get the instance from within an activity.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
String[] newList = yourList.toArray(new String[]);
```

hope this works

Answer (score 1):

```
List<NewsLineTag> tags = response.body().getData().getTags();
List<String> tagStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
//add some stuff
for (NewsLineTag tag : tags) {
    tagStrings.add(tag.getSomeTextValueINeed());
}
chipCloud.addChips(tagStrings.toArray(new String[0]));
```

`getSomeTextValueINeed()` should be replaced with some method which will provide you with the `String` you want to show.

Duplicate of [Converting 'ArrayList<String> to 'String[]' in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042434/converting-arrayliststring-to-string-in-java)

Comment: please edit your code with my above codes. please. I am amateur

Comment: I use this code but show me error :                     `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    list.addAll(response.body().getData().getTags());
                    String[] stringArray = list.toArray(new String[0]);`

Comment: Can you send me true code with my above codes? please

Comment: I've edited the code so you can use it for your case.

Comment: Thanks my friend, but show me this error : `NewsDetailTag cannot be stored in destination array of type java.lang.String[]`

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: Check the edited answer above, please. You can't store NewsDetailTag as String since it's not a String. You need to extract String value you need/want from NewsDetailTag.

Comment: In this line you use `chipCloud.addChips(list.toArray(new String[0]));` . what is `list`? where you initialize `list` ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It should be `tagStrings`, not `list`.

Also, please take a look at @lupz answer since it's much cleaner way of using ChipCloud API. I wasn't aware of it (haven't used it at all) so just wrote it down as you already wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Java's `List` has a pretty convenient [`toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[])) method you can use to convert a List to an Array of the same type.

However, since you have a `List<NewsDetailTag>` you will have to build the new array yourself.

It will look something like this:

```
String[] strings = new String[](list.size())
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    array[i] = list.get(i).getStringField();
}
```

Where `getStringField()` is whatever property on `NewsDetailTag` contains the String you want.

Comment: Thank your my dear friend, can you edit your codes with my above codes? please. I am amateur and I need this. please

Comment: I've given you as much as I can with the code you have posted. If you want to represent your `NewsDetailTag `s as Strings, you need to decide what that String representation looks like, and that's what you put in to the array.