# Why there is a ClassCastException when i try to convert object[] to Student[]?

Tags: java, classcastexception

there is a ClassCastException,I don't know why can't convert Object[] to String[]?

```
package day5;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class JavaLog {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Student> pList = new ArrayList<>();
        pList.add(new Student("Bob", 89));//Student("name", age)
        pList.add(new Student("Mike", 78));
        pList.add(new Student("John", 99));

        Student[] sList = (Student[]) pList.toArray();
        Arrays.sort(sList);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sList));
    }
}

class Student implements Comparable<Student>{
    ...
}
```

when I run the code,I get the ClassCastException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Lday5.Student; ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; [Lday5.Student; is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at day5.JavaLog.main(JavaLog.java:13)
```

Comment: Change it to ```pList.toArray(Student[]::new)```. This might work

Comment: Yes, it worked, but why did my method report an exception?

Comment: Check out the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why `Student[] sList = (Student[]) pList.toArray();` wont work?

Some info from the link right below:

> In Java, generic type exists at compile-time only. At runtime
> information about generic type (like in your case `Student`) is
> removed and replaced with `Object` type (take a look at type erasure).
> That is why at runtime `toArray()` have no idea about what precise type
> to use to create new array, so it uses Object as safest type, because
> each `class extends Object` so it can safely store instance of any
> class.

> **Now the problem is that you can't cast instance of Object[] to Student[].**

> The JVM doesn't know (or more precisely, it is not allowed to do that. If it could do that, it would violate Java type safety) how to blindly downcast `Object[]` (the result of
> toArray()) to `Student[]`. To let it know what your desired object type
> is, you can pass a typed array into `toArray()`.

#### Solution: `pList.toArray(Student[]::new)`

More info: [Converting 'ArrayList<String> to 'String[]' in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042434/converting-arrayliststring-to-string-in-java)